# Android: How to disable vertical scroll of ScrollView when scrolling a HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I am developing an Android app with an Activity with a ScrollView that contains, among other stuff, a HorizontalScrollView. When I touch the HorizontalScrollView I want to disable vertical scrolling of the outer ScrollView. How do I achieve that?

Thanks
Markus

Comment: I have found a marvelous answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14577399/241986

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at

```
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) { }
```

Of the ScrollView classes.