# ListView inside ScrollView is not scrolling on Android

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, scrollview

I am having trouble with a scrolling `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. I have an Activity which has some EditTexts in the top part and then a tab host with two tabs which have one ListView each. When the EditText views are focused, the soft keyboard comes up and as I  have a ScrollView, the content is scrollable. But the problem comes when there are more items in ListViews (ones in tabs), I am not able to scroll the ListView, even if there are more items.

The following is the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="?backgroundImage"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:id="@+id/buttons">
    <Button
            android:text="Save"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:id="@+id/btnSaveorUpdate"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="145dip"></Button>
    <Button
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:id="@+id/btnCancelorDelete"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="145dip"></Button>
  </LinearLayout>
  <ScrollView
        android:layout_above="@id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dip">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dip">
      <TextView
                android:text="Bill details"
                android:textColor="?textColorDark"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/txtEnterDetails"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"></TextView>
      <LinearLayout
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="0dip" />
      <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:hint="Enter data"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:id="@+id/txtSample"
                android:textSize="@dimen/editText"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/editTextHeight"
                android:text=""></EditText>
      <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
                android:hint="Enter description"
                android:textSize="@dimen/editText"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/editTextHeight"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text=""></EditText>
      <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/txtComment"
                android:hint="Enter comment (if any)"
                android:textSize="@dimen/editText"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/editTextHeight"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text=""></EditText>
      <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="20dip"
                    android:textColor="?textColorDark"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/editTextHeight"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnPickDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/editTextHeight"
                    android:text="Select date"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:textSize="15dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <TabHost
                android:id="@+id/tabhost"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
          <TabWidget
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"></TabWidget>
          <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
            <ScrollView
                            android:layout_above="@id/buttons"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:fillViewport="true"
                            android:id="@+id/tab1">
              <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TableLayout
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                  <TableRow
                                        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
                                        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout
                                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                      <ImageView
                                                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_invite"
                                                android:layout_width="40dip"
                                                android:layout_height="40dip"
                                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"></ImageView>
                      <TextView
                                                android:text="Add friend"
                                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                                android:textColor="?textColorDark"
                                                android:textSize="@dimen/editText"
                                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                  </TableRow>
                  <TableRow
                                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                                        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">
                    <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/txtData1"
                                            android:layout_width="170dip"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:text="Data"
                                            android:textSize="14dip"
                                            android:textStyle="bold"
                                            android:textColor="#000000">
                    </TextView>
                    <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/txtData2"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:text="Sample"
                                            android:textSize="13dip"
                                            android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>

                  </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
                <ListView
                                    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                                    android:id="@+id/ListView01"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
              </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:id="@+id/tab2"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
              <TableLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                  <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <ImageView
                                            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_invite"
                                            android:layout_width="40dip"
                                            android:layout_height="40dip"
                                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"></ImageView>
                    <TextView
                                            android:text="Sample"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                            android:textColor="?textColorDark"
                                            android:textSize="@dimen/editText"
                                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                  </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">
                  <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/txtUser1"
                                        android:layout_width="170dip"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="User"
                                        android:textSize="14dip"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        android:textColor="#000000">
                  </TextView>
                  <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/txtUserData"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="UserData"
                                        android:textSize="13dip"
                                        android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>
                </TableRow>
              </TableLayout>

              <ListView
                                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                                android:id="@+id/ListView02"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

            </LinearLayout>


          </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
      </TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please can anyone tell me what the problem is here? I have another post on the ListView inside ScrollView problem, but they were of no use in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)

Comment: I get a solution : http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/12/listview-into-scrollview-in-android.html

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You shouldn't put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` because the `ListView` class implements its own scrolling and it just doesn't receive gestures because they all are handled by the parent `ScrollView`. I strongly recommend you to simplify your layout somehow. For example you can add views you want to be scrolled to the `ListView` as headers or footers.

**UPDATE**:

Starting from API Level 21 (Lollipop) nested scroll containers are officially supported by Android SDK. There're a bunch of methods in `View` and `ViewGroup` classes which provide this functionality. To make nested scrolling work on the Lollipop you have to enable it for a child scroll view by adding `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` to its XML declaration or by explicitly calling `setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)`.

If you want to make nested scrolling work on pre-Lollipop devices, which you probably do, you have to use corresponding utility classes from the Support library. First you have to replace you `ScrollView` with [NestedScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html). The latter implements both [NestedScrollingParent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingParent.html) and [NestedScrollingChild](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html) so it can be used as a parent or a child scroll container.

But `ListView` doesn't support nested scrolling, therefore you need to subclass it and implement `NestedScrollingChild`. Fortunately, the Support library provides [NestedScrollingChildHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChildHelper.html) class, so you just have to create an instance of this class and call its methods from the corresponding methods of your view class.

Comment: Thanks Pixie, but you must have noticed that I am using a tabhost with two tabs each containing a separate listview. In this case how can I add headers or footers?

Comment: Yeah, putting tabs into a `ListView` would be strange. But your layout is very very complicated. I can't even understand what you want it to look like. Anyway you'd better make it simpler because a `ListView` nested into a `ScrollView` which is nested into another `ScrollView` looks strange and will not work.

Comment: Hello Pixie, I removed all the scrollview and now listview scrolling is working. But, now I am facing another problem, when the listview is scrolled, it is not stopping to that item, I mean it is again going to top after scrolling is stopped on listview. How to make listview show the item where scrolling stopped?

Comment: **custom listview inside scrollview** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813296/non-scrollable-listview-inside-scrollview.

Comment: If your layout has some data above listview. You can add header and footer in listview.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978359/using-listview-how-to-add-a-header-view

Comment: yes, it's possible to nest scrollable views, but it also indicates that your layout (and UE design) is a bit complex

Comment: Simple : in child view's TouchListener write v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

Comment: it's work for me : http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/12/listview-into-scrollview-in-android.html

Comment: Thank you for your update. I was finally able to get it working by setting both the ScrollView AND ListView nestedScrollingEnabled=true

Comment: Excellent. android:nestedScrollingEnabled() solved my problem. I put my layout into a ScrollView in order to make room for the UI elements my app needs.

Comment: Is there a way to inflate these expandable list views ? because I am using multiple expandable in one view. thanks

Answer (score 310):

In the Stack Overflow answer at [MapView inside a ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546108/mapview-inside-a-scrollview/6883831#6883831), I found a solution that works excellently and can scroll the `ListView` without problems:

> ```
> ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);  // your
> listview inside scrollview lv.setOnTouchListener(new
> ListView.OnTouchListener() {
>         @Override
>         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
>           int action = event.getAction();
>             switch (action) {
>             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
>                 // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
>                 v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
>                 break;
>
>             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
>                 // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
>                 v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
>                 break;
>             }
>
>             // Handle ListView touch events.
>             v.onTouchEvent(event);
>             return true;
>         }
>     });
> ```

What this does is disable the `TouchEvent`s on the `ScrollView` and make the `ListView`  intercept them. It is simple and works all the time.

Comment: One issue with this, its working well without onitemclick listener, if i want also OnItemClickListener then ?

Comment: This works for nested list views and expandable list views as well. If you have a SwipeRefreshLaout, you will have issues when scrolled all the way up. An easy way to handle that as well is to get an instance of the SwipeRefreshLayout through the parents, and then disable it on down, and re enable it on up.

Comment: Hello @Moisés Olmedo i am trying to use the same method but getting this Custom view HorizontalListView has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override performClick. is there a way to deal with this?

Comment: This is great - I use it to make DragAndDropLinearLayout work inside scrollview - I set the this listener to drag handler and disable the fragment's scrollview. The only difference is that I would return **false** instead of **true** to make drag and drop work.

Comment: @MoisésOlmedo I've followed your answer. It is working perfectly in portrait mode,but not in landscape. I have 11 items in list. All of them are visible in portrait, but in landscape am getting only 6. List is not scrolling.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Please, how do I intercept the top of the list? Because I want to start the refresh, when It is all over

Answer (score 145):

I have also one solution. I always use this method. Try this

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/createdrill_scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

            <net.thepaksoft.fdtrainer.NestedListView
                android:id="@+id/crewList"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
            </net.thepaksoft.fdtrainer.NestedListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

            <net.thepaksoft.fdtrainer.NestedListView
                android:id="@+id/benchmarksList"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
            </net.thepaksoft.fdtrainer.NestedListView>
        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

NestedListView.java class:

```
public class NestedListView extends ListView implements OnTouchListener, OnScrollListener {

    private int listViewTouchAction;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE = 99;

    public NestedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        listViewTouchAction = -1;
        setOnScrollListener(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, -1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int newHeight = 0;
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter != null && !listAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                int listPosition = 0;
                for (listPosition = 0; listPosition < listAdapter.getCount()
                        && listPosition < MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE; listPosition++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(listPosition, null, this);
                    //now it will not throw a NPE if listItem is a ViewGroup instance
                    if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
                        listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }
                    listItem.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                    newHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
                newHeight += getDividerHeight() * listPosition;
            }
            if ((heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) && (newHeight > heightSize)) {
                if (newHeight > heightSize) {
                    newHeight = heightSize;
                }
            }
        } else {
            newHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), newHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, 1);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. While all other solutions only work when list-items are of same size, this solution out-stands those when list-items have variable height. Spent some hours & at last found this.

Comment: Its work but for load more functionality is not working, how it is possible?

Comment: Scrollview can host only one direct child.How is it possible.

Comment: @MuhammadAamirALi, can you please tell me how to instantiate the NestedListView class ? I don't quite understand what AttributSet value should be. Thanks.

Comment: What do I need to do to customize this solution for expandable listview?

Comment: I found a major issue with this solution. It defeats the entire purpose of list view. It essentially performs a load of all list views (not just the visible ones) and changes the height to engulf them all (more like a `LinearLayout` rather than a `ListView`. This means that if you have a large number of list items (or complex list items) then the android devices will take a lot of time to open the activity (or even crash while trying in my case).

Comment: worst idea ever ... [You've just recreated a very expensive LinearLayout :) –  Romain Guy(google engineer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing#comment-3652403) ... this solution is only for noobs who do not fully understand the ListView ... @reubenjohn you are absolutely right

Comment: Beware to use it. No, do not use it. It consumes lots of CPU in for loop `onMeasure` calculation.

Answer (score 49):

You have to just replace your `<ScrollView ></ScrollView>` with this `Custom ScrollView` like     `<com.tmd.utils.VerticalScrollview > </com.tmd.utils.VerticalScrollview >`

```
package com.tmd.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class VerticalScrollview extends ScrollView{

    public VerticalScrollview(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

     public VerticalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public VerticalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: DOWN super false" );
                    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                    break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    return false; // redirect MotionEvents to ourself

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: CANCEL super false" );
                    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                    break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: UP super false" );
                    return false;

            default: Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: " + action ); break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onTouchEvent. action: " + ev.getAction() );
         return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Atul this work like good on devices: Samsung captiavte i897, HTC Sensation, HTC Incredible, but does not work on HTC Desire x, what may be the problem?

Comment: @Atul but is scrolls sometimes when using 3 or 4 fingers but sometimes.

Comment: @pepela you are right.Sometimes its not as smooth as only one scroll View. But it fulfill our need.

Comment: It can intercept all the motions when scroll large listview. as for me, i use this patch: http://pristalovpavel.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/doing-it-right-vertical-scrollview-with-viewpager-and-listview/

Answer (score 11):

I had a same issue and while googling I found your question. Yes marked answer worked for me also but there was some issue.
 Anyways I found another [solution](http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/scrollview-inside-scrollview-scrolling-problem/). 
which works perfectly without doing any jugglery.

Comment: Please post answer on SO, not just link to external site.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is asked long ago, but who ever is stuck for now can solve this by adding this line into your ListView

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

For Example -

```
                    <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the following method and enjoy!

```
private void setListViewScrollable(final ListView list) {
    list.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            listViewTouchAction = event.getAction();
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                list.scrollBy(0, 1);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                list.scrollBy(0, -1);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

listViewTouchAction is a global integer value.
If you can replace the line

```
list.scrollBy(0, 1);
```

with something else please share it with us.

Enjoy!

Comment: Very close. It still doesn't work in many times, but at least it works in a few times.

Comment: Its Working but the problem is with the speed of the scroll. Its very laggy.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the exact method of using Listview with in the Scrollview. All we have to handle touch events.

```
      lstvNextTracks.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
      {
          @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
          {
         Log.e("Lisview *************", "focused");
         SCView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
         return false;
          }
      });




    SCView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            int arr[] = new int[] { 1, 2 };
            lstvNextTracks.getLocationOnScreen(arr);

            /* Get bounds of child Listview*/
            int lstvTop = arr[0];
            int lstvBottom = arr[1] + lstvNextTracks.getHeight();
            int lstvLeft = arr[1];
            int lstvRight = arr[0] + lstvNextTracks.getWidth();

            float x = event.getRawX();
            float y = event.getRawY();

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                /*check if child ListView bounds are touched*/
                if (x > lstvTop && x < lstvBottom && y > lstvLeft && y < lstvRight)
                {
                    SCView.clearFocus();
                    /*This statement tells the ScrollView to do not handle this touch event, so the child Listview will handle this touch event and will scroll */
                    SCView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    /*The child Listview isFocusable attribute must be set to true otherwise it will not work*/
                    lstvNextTracks.requestFocus();
                    return true;
                } else
                    return false;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {

                if (x > lstvTop && x < lstvBottom && y > lstvLeft && y < lstvRight)
                {
                    SCView.clearFocus();
                    SCView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    lstvNextTracks.requestFocus();
                    return true;
                } else
                    return false;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                SCView.clearFocus();
                SCView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                lstvNextTracks.requestFocus();
                return false;
            } else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: has a bug when the scroll area is out of touch area

Answer (score 4):

Its a bad practice to have two different scrolling views together. ListView itself has its own scrolling functionality and height is auto adjusted according to Adapter settings for your row items (Keelping in mind, we are not setting specific height to ListView in our Layout xml). However in your case, you can replace ListView with a class and this will adjust height for your ListView keeping in mind that your ListView is inside ScrollView.

This will help you:

```
public class ExpandableHeightListview extends ListView
{

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightListview(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded()
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded())
        {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
            // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

Now extend your ListView with this class, just change your ListView tag from your resource xml to smothing like this,

```
<yourpackagename.ExpandableHeightListview
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:fadingEdge="none">
            </cyourpackagename.ExpandableHeightListview>
```

This will solve your scrolling problem of ListView, as now the parent scrolling is managed by ScrollView rather then ListView.

Comment: Does this allows the ListView to scroll inside NestedScrollView ??

Comment: Yes, it will allow. As through this solution, the listview scrolling properties will be disabled, and the parent scrollview would be responsible to scroll the listview contents. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I've similar issue and resolved by creating custom class by extending with ListView.

**ScrollableListView.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ScrollableListView extends ListView {

    public ScrollableListView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScrollableListView (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScrollableListView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<com.my.package.ScrollableListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: UIHaq Does this allows the ListView to scroll inside NestedScrollView ??

Comment: It's not working for multilevel ExpandableListview like 3 level or 4 level. Any help??

Answer (score 2):

Add:
`android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"`

Comment: confirmed ! only adding this  is  enough,  either the  list is inside the  scrollview or scrollview is inside the  listview

Answer (score 1):

Demo_ListView_In_ScrollView

==============================

```
            package com.app.custom_seekbar;
            
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.widget.ListView;
            
            public class Demo_ListView_In_ScrollView  extends Activity
            {
                ListView listview;
                ArrayList<String> data=null;
                listview_adapter adapter=null;
                
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    super.setContentView(R.layout.demo_listview_in_scrollview_activity);
                    init();
                    set_data();
                    set_adapter();
                    
                
                }
                public void init()
                {
                    listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                    data=new ArrayList<String>();
                    
                }
                public void set_data()
                {
                    data.add("Meet");
                    data.add("prachi");
                    data.add("shailesh");
                    data.add("manoj");
                    data.add("sandip");
                    data.add("zala");
                    data.add("tushar");
                    data.add("Meet");
                    data.add("prachi");
                    data.add("shailesh");
                    data.add("manoj");
                    data.add("sandip");
                    data.add("zala");
                    data.add("tushar");
                    data.add("Meet");
                    data.add("prachi");
                    data.add("shailesh");
                    data.add("manoj");
                    data.add("sandip");
                    data.add("zala");
                    data.add("tushar");
                    data.add("Meet");
                    data.add("prachi");
                    data.add("shailesh");
                    data.add("manoj");
                    data.add("sandip");
                    data.add("zala");
                    data.add("tushar");
                    data.add("Meet");
                    data.add("prachi");
                    data.add("shailesh");
                    data.add("manoj");
                    data.add("sandip");
                    data.add("zala");
                    data.add("tushar");
                    data.add("Meet");
                    data.add("prachi");
                    data.add("shailesh");
                    data.add("manoj");
                    data.add("sandip");
                    data.add("zala");
                    data.add("tushar");
                    data.add("Meet");
                    data.add("prachi");
                    data.add("shailesh");
                    data.add("manoj");
                    data.add("sandip");
                    data.add("zala");
                    data.add("tushar");
                    data.add("Meet");
                    data.add("prachi");
                    data.add("shailesh");
                    data.add("manoj");
                    data.add("sandip");
                    data.add("zala");
                    data.add("tushar");
                    data.add("Meet");
                    data.add("prachi");
                    data.add("shailesh");
                    data.add("manoj");
                    data.add("sandip");
                    data.add("zala");
                    data.add("tushar");
                    data.add("Meet");
                    data.add("prachi");
                    data.add("shailesh");
                    data.add("manoj");
                    data.add("sandip");
                    data.add("zala");
                    data.add("tushar");
                    data.add("Meet");
                    data.add("prachi");
                    data.add("shailesh");
                    data.add("manoj");
                    data.add("sandip");
                    data.add("zala");
                    data.add("tushar");
                    data.add("Meet");
                    data.add("prachi");
                    data.add("shailesh");
                    data.add("manoj");
                    data.add("sandip");
                    data.add("zala");
                    data.add("tushar");
                    data.add("Meet");
                    data.add("prachi");
                    data.add("shailesh");
                    data.add("manoj");
                    data.add("sandip");
                    data.add("zala");
                    data.add("tushar");
                    
                    
                    
                }
            
                public void set_adapter()
                {
                    adapter=new listview_adapter(Demo_ListView_In_ScrollView.this,data);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                    Helper.getListViewSize(listview); // set height of listview according to Arraylist item  
                }
                    
            }
```

========================

listview_adapter

==========================

```
        package com.app.custom_seekbar;
        
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.MotionEvent;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.LinearLayout;
        import android.widget.ScrollView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        
        public class listview_adapter  extends ArrayAdapter<String>  
        {
            private final Activity context;
            ArrayList<String>data;
            class ViewHolder 
            {
                public TextView tv_name;
                public ScrollView scroll;
                public LinearLayout l1;
            }
            
        
            public listview_adapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> all_data) {
                super(context, R.layout.item_list_xml, all_data);
                this.context = context;
                data=all_data;
            }
            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View rowView = convertView;
                ViewHolder viewHolder;
                if (rowView == null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_xml, null);
                    
                    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                    
                    viewHolder.tv_name=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    
                    rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
                }
                else
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
                
                viewHolder.tv_name.setText(data.get(position).toString());
                return rowView;
                
            }
            
            
        }
```

===================================

Helper class (source: https://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/12/listview-into-scrollview-in-android.html)

====================================

```
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    
    public class Helper {
        public static void getListViewSize(ListView myListView) {
            ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
            if (myListAdapter == null) {
                //do nothing return null
                return;
            }
            //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
            int totalHeight = 0;
            for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
                View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
                listItem.measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
          //setting listview item in adapter
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() *                   (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
            // print height of adapter on log
            Log.i("height of listItem:", String.valueOf(totalHeight));
        }
    }
```

========================

demo_listview_in_scrollview_activity.xml

========================

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
        
                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        
        </LinearLayout>
```

================

item_list_xml.xml

==================

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should probably explain a bit, a mass of code isn't that great as an answer without an explanation.

Comment: I used to this solution. But this solution is not good. Becuz my list have 10 items, but it display 9.5 or 9 items.

Answer (score 1):

### requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (boolean disallowIntercept)

> Called when a child does not want this parent and its ancestors to intercept touch events with onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent).
>     This parent should pass this call onto its parents. This parent must obey this request for the duration of the touch (that is, only clear the flag after this parent has received an up or a cancel.

Try this answer,

```
    listview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

// Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
            scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            int action = event.getActionMasked();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use NestedScrollVew with RecyclerView or if you want to go with Listview then you can add header and footer view to this.
For example:

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.outofoffice_footer_view, null, false);
infoListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried and tested nearly all the methods mentioned above, trust me, after completely running away from RecyclerView, I replaced my ListView with RecyclerView and it worked perfectly. Didnt need any 3rd Party library for ExtendedHeightListView and all, just plain and simple RecyclerView.

So Heres my Layout file before recyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="5dp">

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    tools:context="com.example.android.udamovappv3.activities.DetailedActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:background="#079ED9"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/my_toolbar_detail"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_poster"
        android:layout_width="131dp"
        android:layout_height="163dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/my_toolbar_detail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_name"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_mark_as_fav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv_poster"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:background="#079ED9"
        android:text="Mark As \n Favorite"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_runTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_rating"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_releaseDate"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_releaseDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_runTime"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_poster"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bt_mark_as_fav"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_runTime"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_overview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_poster"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:text="adasdasdfadfsasdfasdfasdfasdfnb agfjuanfalsbdfjbdfklbdnfkjasbnf;kasbdnf;kbdfas;kdjabnf;lbdnfo;aidsnfl';asdfj'plasdfj'pdaskjf'asfj'p[asdfk"
        android:textColor="#000000"
         />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_overview">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_dds_review_textView_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reviews:"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        <com.github.paolorotolo.expandableheightlistview.ExpandableHeightListView
            android:id="@+id/expandable_listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_dds_review_textView_label"
            android:padding="8dp">

        </com.github.paolorotolo.expandableheightlistview.ExpandableHeightListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

THIS IS AFTER REPLACING MY LISTVIEW WITH ONE OF THE MANY SOLUTIONS MENTIONED ABOVE. So the problem was that the listview was not behaving properly due to 2 scrollview bug(maybe not a bug) in android.

I replaced the 
with recycler view to form form my final layout.

This is my recycler view adapter:

```
public class TrailerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TrailerAdapter.TrailerAdapterViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> Youtube_URLS;

private Context Context;

public TrailerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> Youtube_URLS){
    this.Context = context;
    this.Youtube_URLS = Youtube_URLS;
}
@Override
public TrailerAdapter.TrailerAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.trailer_layout, parent, false);
    return new TrailerAdapterViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TrailerAdapter.TrailerAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.with(Context).load(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp).into(holder.iv_playbutton);
    holder.item_id.setText(Youtube_URLS.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(Youtube_URLS.size()==0){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return Youtube_URLS.size();
    }
}

public class TrailerAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView iv_playbutton;
    TextView item_id;

    public TrailerAdapterViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        iv_playbutton = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        item_id = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trailer_sequence);
    }
}
}
```

And this is my RecyclerView custom layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_trailer_sequence"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/play_button"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And VOILA, I got the desired effect of ListView(Now RecyclerView) within a scollview. 
[Heres the Final Image of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8FS7.png)

On a final note, I believe that replacing the RecyclerView was a better choice for me, as it improved the overall app stability, and also helped me understand RecyclerView better. If I were to suggest a solution, Im going to say replace your ListView with a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this error.And my solution is following as:

**1. Create a custom listview which is non scrollable**

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();    
}
```

}

**2. Use above custom class for xml file**

```
  <com.Example.NonScrollListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_nonscroll_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.Example.NonScrollListView>
```

Hope best for you.

Comment: Does this allows the ListView to scroll inside NestedScrollView ?? I think it resize the Listview as per the item size.

Comment: It's not working for multilevel ExpandableListview like 3 level or 4 level. Any help??

Answer (score 1):

Above solution given by @Shailesh Rohit works perfectly fine. Some tricks has to be done.

1. If you are putting helper class inside the same class( main class) then make Helper class as static and getListViewSize() not be static.
2. Most important, write "Helper.getListViewSize(listView);" statement after setting adapter for the first time like "listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);" as well as when ever you are using "myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();"
3. Usage is shown below.

   listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
   myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listValues);
   listView .setAdapter(myAdapter);
   Helper.getListViewSizelistView(listView);

   myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   Helper.getListViewSizelistView(listView);

Answer (score 1):

Best Code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/btmlyt"
android:layout_below="@+id/deshead_tv">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/des_tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btmlyt"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:text="description"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best example

Add NestedScrollView instead of Scrollview

Add this line in ListView `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"`

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >       
        <ListView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
             />          
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

As According to me while you are using setOnTouchListener om parent or child stop the scrolling of parent as you touch on child else stop scrolling of child as you touch on parent

Answer (score 0):

Try this with ScrollView, not with ListView.

```
public class xScrollView extends ScrollView
{
    ;
    ;
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you format the code ?? the answer has empty lines with semi colon and no comments

Comment: If you don't do much with your extended ScrollView, you don't need to write something in the lines with semi colons. So just remove them. And suppose your package name 'com.me', then in the layout XML, use '<com.me.xScrollView ...' instead of '<ScrollView ...'

Answer (score 0):

replace ListView by RecycleView inside ScrollView. it runs smoothly without additional source code:

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hung.recycleviewtest.MainActivityFragment"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycle_view_a"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/recycle_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

For ListView inside ScrollView use NestedScrollView it can handle this
functionality very easily:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dip"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that,
**Instead of using scrollview, You can use addHeaderview and addFooterview of listview**

Here is my snippet,

```
//  create separate layout and add it dynamically
    scrollview=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourlayout,null);
    lv=(ListView)listview.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    lv.addHeaderView(scrollview);
    lv.setContentView(lv);
```

Now, with the listview your layout also can be scrolled. Enjoy it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace ScrollView by android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView inside xml. it runs

1) Use in XML::::      `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`

instead of:::: `ScrollView`

2) And use for list view in this way using NonScrollListView in cs file:

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {    

    public NonScrollListView(Context context) {    
        super(context);
    }    
    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }    
}
```

3) Finally use this code to identify scrollview in cs file:

```
NonScrollListView listView = (NonScrollListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

Comment: Does this allows the ListView to scroll inside NestedScrollView ??

Comment: It's not working for multilevel ExpandableListview like 3 level or 4 level. Any help??

Answer (score -1):

You cannot add a ListView in a scroll View, as list view also scolls and there would be a synchonization problem between listview scroll and scroll view scoll.
You can make a CustomList View and add this method into it.

```
@Override 
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    /*
     * Prevent parent controls from stealing our events once we've gotten a touch down
     */
    if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ViewParent p = getParent();
        if (p != null) {
            p.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Dont give scroll view to `ListView`, coz it has that setting default

```
<ListView
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:id="@+id/ListView01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```