# ListView is not scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview inside an AbsoluteLayout , and is not scrolling.

the XML is :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listTrauma"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="178dp"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
     android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_y="666dp" >
</ListView>
```

and the adapter code:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.test1, dataTrauma);
```

Comment: Do never use `AbsoluteLayout`. Ever!

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210756/why-is-my-listview-not-scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey AbsoluteLayout is deprecated. Its good to use either LineaLayout or RelativeLayout.
You can go through [**this**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts) for more information. `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` will occupy the space and add some elements in that list.It will scroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <ListView
           android:id="@+id/listTrauma"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

And I guess in your case you have given a specific height to your list, I guess that's why it's not scrolling.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use linear layout instead of absolute layout. And also, edit your list view properties, and use something like this:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listTrauma"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="none"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RelativeLayout` instead of the `AbsoluteLayout`. The `AbsoluteLayout` was `deprectated` in API level 3: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html