# Unable to scroll the listview in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that, I am adding listview in LinearLayout dynamically through code and set the EndlessAdapter into that, Data is shown correctly but we are unable to scroll from top to bottom in the list. I don't know why? please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

**Code:**

```
public void setValuesInCategoryChild(String url, final String filter,
            final String from, final String to) {
        if (isOnline()) {
            final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                    ResearchList.this, "Research List       ",
                    "Please wait...   ", true);

            final Handler handler = new Handler() {

                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    // System.out.println("The id after Save:"+id.get(0).toString());

                    // catagory.addAll(keyword_vector1);
                    linear_Category_Child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    linear_Category_Child_Child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // tv_Child_Header.setText("Volvo");
                    tv_CategoryChildHeader.setText(from);
                    setHeaderImage(tv_CategoryChildHeader.getText().toString());
                    System.out.println("The size of Cat Display names:"
                            + coll.getDisplayNames().size());
                    System.out.println("The size of Cat Images:"
                            + coll.getImages().size());
                    System.out.println("The size of Cat price:"
                            + coll.getPrice().size());
                    System.out.println("The size of Cat Year:"
                            + coll.getYears().size());
                    System.out.println("The size of Cat Rating:"
                            + coll.getRating().size());
                    System.out.println("The size of Cat Mpg:"
                            + coll.getMpg().size());
                    setHeaderImage(tv_CategoryChildHeader.getText().toString());
                    if(coll.getDisplayNames().size()!=0)
                    {
                        lvCategory = new ListView(ResearchList.this);
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

                        lvCategory.setLayoutParams(params);

                    // Adapter for MPG Search
                    demoAdapterCat = new DemoAdapterCat();
                    lvCategory.setAdapter(demoAdapterCat);
                    layout_ResearchList_BrandList.addView(lvCategory);
                    Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lvCategory);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /*lvCategory.invalidate();
                        lvCategory.setAdapter(null);*/
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(ResearchList.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Attention!");
                        builder.setMessage("No Data Available for the Particular Search.");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    }
                                });

                        builder.create().show();
                    }
                    /*Utility util = new Utility();
                    util.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lvCategory);*/
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            };

            final Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    try {
                        String sortEncode = URLEncoder.encode("mpg");
                        String filterEncode = URLEncoder.encode(filter);
                        String clientEncode = URLEncoder.encode("10030812");
                        String fromEncode = URLEncoder.encode(from);
                        String toEncode = URLEncoder.encode(to);
                        String catUrl = "/v1/vehicles/get-make-models.json?sort="
                                + sortEncode
                                + "&filter="
                                + filterEncode
                                + "&client-id="
                                + clientEncode
                                + "&from="
                                + fromEncode;
                        genSig = new GetSignature(catUrl, "acura");
                        try {
                            signature = genSig.getUrlFromString();
                        } catch (InvalidKeyException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        // jsonString =
                        // getJsonSring("http://api.highgearmedia.com/v1/vehicles/get-models.json?make=acura&client-id=10030812&signature=LWQbdAlJVxlXZ1VO2mfqAA==");
                        // String signatureEncode =
                        // URLEncoder.encode(signature);
                        String urlEncode = URLEncoder.encode(catUrl
                                + "&signature=" + signature);
                        jsonString = getJsonSring("http://apibeta.highgearmedia.com"
                                + catUrl + "&signature=" + signature);
                        System.out.println("The json category:===>"
                                + jsonString);
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JsonParse json = new JsonParse(jsonString);
                    json.parseCat();
                    LIST_SIZE = coll.getDisplayNames().size();
                    for (int i = 0; i <= BATCH_SIZE; i++) {
                        // countriesSub.add(COUNTRIES[i]);
                        countriesSubCat.add(coll.getDisplayNames().get(i));
                        imagesSubCat.add(coll.getImages().get(i));
                        YearSubCat1.add(coll.getYears().get(i));
                        YearSubCat2.add(coll.getYears().get(i + 1));
                        mpgSubCat1.add(coll.getMpg().get(i));
                        mpgSubCat2.add(coll.getMpg().get(i + 1));
                        priceSubCat1.add(coll.getPrice().get(i));
                        priceSubCat2.add(coll.getPrice().get(i + 1));
                        ratingSubCat1.add(coll.getRating().get(i));
                        ratingSubCat2.add(coll.getRating().get(i + 1));
                    }
                    setLastOffset(BATCH_SIZE);
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                }

            };
            checkUpdate.start();
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(ResearchList.this);
            builder.setTitle("Attention!");
            builder.setMessage("Network Connection unavailable.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });

            builder.create().show();
        }

    }
```

**Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_ResearchListCategoryChild_Child"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_ResearchListCategoryChild_Child_HeaderBlock"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:background="@drawable/catagory_bar"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_ResearchListCategoryChild_Child_Header"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="Work in Progress"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginLeft="60dip"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_ResearchListCategory_ChildHeader"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/up_arrow" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/list_arrow_up" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_ResearchListCategoryChild_Child_Header"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:background="@drawable/nav_bg"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:text="Highest Rated"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:text="A-Z"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:text="Price"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:text="MPG"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <!--
                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/relative_down_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    >

                </RelativeLayout>

                -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearArrowLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/Highly_rated"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/selector_arrow"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/AZ_arrow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/selector_arrow"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/Price_arrow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/selector_arrow"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/MPG"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/selector_arrow"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dip" android:background="#ffffff" android:id="@+id/layout_ResearchList_BrandList">
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

**DemoAdapterCat:(Edited)**

```
class DemoAdapterCat extends EndlessAdapter {
        ImageLoader image = new ImageLoader(ResearchList.this);
        private RotateAnimation rotate = null;
        ArrayList<String> tempListNamesCat = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListImagesCat = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListYearCat1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListYearCat2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListmpgCat1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListmpgCat2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListpriceCat1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListpriceCat2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListRatingCat1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListRatingCat2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        DemoAdapterCat() {
            super(new CategoryListLazyAdapter(ResearchList.this,
                    countriesSubCat, imagesSubCat, YearSubCat1, YearSubCat2,
                    mpgSubCat1, mpgSubCat2, priceSubCat1, priceSubCat2,
                    ratingSubCat1, ratingSubCat2));
            /*Utility util = new Utility();
            util.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lvCategory);*/
            rotate = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotate.setDuration(600);
            rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
            rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        }

        /*
         * @Override public int getCount() { return
         * brandList.getDisplayNames().size(); //return count+=10; }
         */
        @Override
        protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) {
            row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.categorylist, null);

            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_Name);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_MPG1);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_MPG2);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_Price1);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_Price2);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_Rating1);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_Rating2);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_Year1);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_Year2);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.linear_CategoryList_itemlayer1);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.linear_CategoryList_itemlayer2);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            /*
             * child = row.findViewById(R.id.img_CategoryItem);
             * child.setVisibility(View.GONE); child =
             * row.findViewById(R.id.img_CategoryItem_Arrow);
             * child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             */

            /*
             * child = row.findViewById(R.id.linear_main_MPG);
             * child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             */
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.throbber);
            child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            child.startAnimation(rotate);

            return (row);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean cacheInBackground() {
            //count += 10;
            SystemClock.sleep(100000);
            tempListNamesCat.clear();
            tempListImagesCat.clear();
            tempListmpgCat1.clear();
            tempListmpgCat2.clear();
            tempListpriceCat1.clear();
            tempListpriceCat2.clear();
            tempListYearCat1.clear();
            tempListYearCat2.clear();
            tempListRatingCat1.clear();
            tempListRatingCat2.clear();
//          countriesSubCat.clear();
//          imagesSubCat.clear();
//          YearSubCat1.clear();
//          YearSubCat2.clear();
//          mpgSubCat1.clear();
//          mpgSubCat2.clear();
//          priceSubCat1.clear();
//          priceSubCat2.clear();
//          ratingSubCat1.clear();
//          ratingSubCat2.clear();

            int lastOffset = getLastOffset();
            if (lastOffset < LIST_SIZE) {
                int limit = lastOffset + BATCH_SIZE;
                for (int i = (lastOffset + 1); (i <= limit && i < LIST_SIZE); i++) {
                    tempListNamesCat.add(coll.getDisplayNames().get(i));
                    tempListImagesCat.add(coll.getImages().get(i));
                    tempListmpgCat1.add(coll.getMpg().get(i));
                    tempListmpgCat2.add(coll.getMpg().get(i + 1));
                    tempListpriceCat1.add(coll.getPrice().get(i));
                    tempListpriceCat2.add(coll.getPrice().get(i + 1));
                    tempListRatingCat1.add(coll.getRating().get(i));
                    tempListRatingCat2.add(coll.getRating().get(i + 1));
                    tempListYearCat1.add(coll.getYears().get(i));
                    tempListYearCat2.add(coll.getYears().get(i + 1));
                }

                setLastOffset(limit);

                if (limit < LIST_SIZE) {
                    // return true;
                    return (getWrappedAdapter().getCount() < coll
                            .getDisplayNames().size());
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void appendCachedData() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            // Activity activity = this;
            // ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapterNew =
            // (ArrayAdapter<String>)getWrappedAdapter();
            CategoryListLazyAdapter arrAdapterNewCategory = (CategoryListLazyAdapter) getWrappedAdapter();
            // int listLen = tempList.size();
            // int listLen = tempListNames.size();
            countriesSubCat.addAll(tempListNamesCat);
            imagesSubCat.addAll(tempListImagesCat);
            mpgSubCat1.addAll(tempListmpgCat1);
            mpgSubCat2.addAll(tempListmpgCat2);
            priceSubCat1.addAll(tempListpriceCat1);
            priceSubCat2.addAll(tempListpriceCat2);
            ratingSubCat1.addAll(tempListRatingCat1);
            ratingSubCat2.addAll(tempListRatingCat2);
            YearSubCat1.addAll(tempListYearCat1);
            YearSubCat2.addAll(tempListYearCat2);
            arrAdapterNewCategory.notifyDataSetChanged();
            /*Utility util = new Utility();
            util.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lvCategory);*/
            /*
             * for(int i=0; i<listLen; i++){ //
             * arrAdapterNew.add(tempList.get(i)); }
             */
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you adding values into the `demoAdapterCat`?

Comment: Please see my Edited part of the question for DemoAdapterCat EndlessAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

You  need to set **android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"** to its XML declaration 
**OR**
By explicitly calling **setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)**.

> *Check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6211286*