# ListView and LinearLayout overLapping

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have layout like this 
At the top i have listView ,below that i have LinearLayout (the one with radio button Add New Addess). 

Now Issue is my listView and linearlayout are overlapping . Kindly help me .

[image]

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/hs18_logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/setting_icon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/menu" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/signin_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/setting_icon"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/signin"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cart_checkout_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Shipping Address"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/shipping_addresses_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.90" >
    </ListView>

    <include layout="@layout/shipping_add_adresss" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape_white"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/red" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape_red"
            android:text="Update Shipping Address"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout></ScrollView>
```

Comment: @DevuSoman : will it add the linearlayout at the end last element of listview

Comment: where is closing of srollview. put your full xml code.

Comment: @sandy : check the edit .. some issue with SO

Comment: get your listview out of scrollview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android?rq=1

Comment: @sandy : my view is large . if i remove scrollview ..my layout wont fit on screen ..... my main aim is just to place these layout at the end of the listview

Comment: @MohitSharma You can do one thing: have only ListView in the Layout.xml. And **my main aim is just to place these layout at the end of the listview**, you can set that huge layout as a FooterView to your ListView. That way, you will see only the ListView initailly and once you scroll to the end of the List, you can see your LinearLayout. But how big is your ListView(how many items?) moreover  does the count change frequently?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc : Max 10 elements  and layout which i want to add is show n in figure .

Comment: Thanks for Effort .. All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MohitSharma Always remember

**Never use a ListView in a ScrollView**

for reasons check this:

[ListView inside ScrollView is not scrolling on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android)

What ever the requirement is you can do it by using just one of them(ListView or ScrollView).

So, for your case you can do either of the 2 things below:

- Have only ListView in your Layout.xml and you can set that huge
  layout as a FooterView to your ListView.
- If you want to use a ScrollView, remove the ListView and dynamically
  add those List Items as normal Layouts(Linear/RelativeLayout).

first approach is more recommended.

Comment: Because if its a static List with <10 items, you can avoid using ListView and just add them to the ScrollView like other Layouts

Comment: You will be adding the FooterView after inflating the Layout. So, once you have a View, you can play around with it. Like `CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) mFooter.findViewById(R.id.mfooter);`

Comment: Hi .. sorry to bug u again .. i have another problem ... my spinner is not able to get itemselect listerner .. .. Pls .. help me

Answer (score 1):

use `layout_above` property for listview.

```
android:layout_above="@+id/linear_layout"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this work for you i have checked it.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical" 
>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="5dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="63dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/hs18_logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/setting_icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/menu" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/signin_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/setting_icon"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/signin"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cart_checkout_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Shipping Address"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/shipping_addresses_listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

& if you Add Layout After Listview Give id to scrollview & add Layout in Scrollview this is perfectly work for you.

Comment: what do mean by " & if you Add Layout After Listview Give id to scrollview & add Layout in Scrollview this is perfectly work for you."