# can ListView be inside ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

can we have ListView inside ExpandableListView so that I can have group level first and then array of child (listView). i already finish from listview classes and it works perfectly!
but how to call each group in expandable list view to display list view (layout)! and get the correct child !
please can any one help !
thanks.

Comment: Put listview in layout what You use for row of ExpandableListView

Comment: can i get more explanation ? thanks

Answer (score 12):

Actually you can put a scrollable view (e.g. your ListView) inside another scrollable view (e.g. your ExpandableListView) and make the former scrollable in the following way:

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // disallow the onTouch for your scrollable parent view 
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! But the real thing is to create a listView in a expandableView.
Here is the trick: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/android-expandablelistview-magic

Comment: Should be https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/android-expandablelistview-magic

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190949/is-it-posible-to-have-separatedlistadapter-inside-expandablelistadapter/) which was asked two days ago. The user there was trying to put a custom view, derived from ListView into ExpandableListView. My answer to that question applies to your case as well, so I'll quote it:

> You can't do that because you can't put a scrollable view(ListView)
>   into another scrollable view(ExpandableListView). The reason is that
>   the parent will consume all the touch events and they will never reach
>   the child. ExpandableListView will scroll, but the ListView will never
>   know that scrolling took place.