# Android ExpandableListView dynamically Load more items when scroll to the Bottom of each group

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am loading dataset of 25 items at a time in the expandable list view groups. I want to load next 25 items whenever user reaches to the last item of any group until all the items have been loaded. I am able to do that with list view but I unable to replicate it with ExpandableListView, as whenever I am scrolling all the groups attached to the ExpandableListView are getting scrolled, So I am unable to find the exact position where I have reached.

Comment: tried `getExpandableListPosition` or similar methods of `ExpandableListView`?

Comment: I tried another way. I used one child Item for every group element and in that child element itself gave listview as layout. Apart from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234349/can-listview-be-inside-expandablelistview) helped to scroll the list view .

Comment: BTW for that particular case if you want to check if you are at the bottom just use `if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) {...`