# List view inside expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Hi I want to display list view when we expand the expandable list  I want the childview as list view inside the expandable list how can I do that kindly help me thanks

Comment: Share your code. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can ListView be inside ExpandableListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234349/can-listview-be-inside-expandablelistview)