# ViewPager for vertical scrolling

Tags: android

Is it possible to use ViewPager in some way as an alternative to vertical scrolling of TextViews (or any other similar View) whose content exceeds the size of screen? I do not want to create as many as instance of TextViews because beforehand I wouldnt know where the piece of text ends on a page. I wonder how Amazon kindle app is implemented to work in desired way.

Comment: can't you just a ListView?

Comment: @blackbelt I guess ListView is for simple work but i need to create page flipping appearance instead of vertical scrolling

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager doesn't design for that certain use.

You can use:

1) Horizontal ListView.

2) Horizontal ScrolView(Add/Remove elements from it as needed).

Use [ZoomableTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848884/zoomable-textview-in-scrollview) with one of 1 or 2,