# Unable to scroll listView

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

I am having a xml file in which UI elements are arranged in the  following sequence. The data I am parsing is being populated on the listView but the listView is not scrollable.Please help me

```
ImageView
TextView
imageView
ListView
imageView
```

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_now_playing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_DailyLimit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_now_playing"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_PlayArea"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewEpisodes"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
                android:divider="@android:color/black"
                android:dividerHeight="5dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_Characters"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_PlayArea"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_DailyLimit"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: if you want to scroll whole layout with listview then use header and footer view of listview.

Comment: @Ketan can you please clear your answer, I didnot get it

Comment: I feel it is worth mentioning why you shouldn't put a ListView inside a ScrollView. 1) As @prateek pointed out is a UX problem. 2) Is a technical problem: a ScrollView allows its child to assume it has an infinite height (its content isn't bound by its own size since it can scroll). A strong advantage of a ListView is view recycling, which will not happen as the ListView will inflate the entire adapter since it thinks it has enough room to show them all.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a big mistake here by placing the `Listview` inside `Scrollview`. Remove `Scrollview` and User`RelativeLayout` as the Top parent and the `Listview` will scroll.

> Also a UX suggestion is never ever use two scrollable items in side
>   one another as user would never be able to know what has to be
>   scrolled. And similarly you won't be able to recognize what is user
>   trying to scroll.

**Suggestion**

---

**You can do one thing. Just keep your TextView inside the Scrollview and below it keep your `listview` but don't make the whole layout scrollable. i.e. two elements can be scrolled but not the whole screen with scrollable elements.**

Comment: this should be comment.

Comment: @prateek will that make the entire layout scrollable ?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I have edited my answer hope it isn't a comment. So you may remove your downvote :)

Comment: @prateek I have edited as per the changes, layout is not scrollable. my textview is too large. hence I have made it scrollable

Comment: @onkar try with my answer. this can also be helpfull when you want multipule listview inside scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Never put a listView inside a scrollView. Never ever.

Watch his great video to know more abt listView

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 0):

ListView does not need inside the ScrollView to make it scrollable because ListView will be scrollable if the content is too long.

Comment: my textview is too large. hence I have made it scrollable

Answer (score 0):

You can put listview inside scrollview. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18354096/942224

and set this value of listview

```
yourListView.setExpanded(true);
```

Comment: ExpandableHeightListView listView=(ExpandableHeightListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableHeightlist1);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  listView.setExpanded(true);

Its still not working :(

Comment: have you set android:focusable="false"
        android:scrollbars="none" this ?

Comment: which kind of problem are you getting?

Comment: i had also same problem .. but using this yourListView.setExpanded(true); it solved. :)