# Android customAdapter (BasesAdapter) getView is always returning 0

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter, custom-adapter, getview

I have made a customadapter for a listview, but for some reason the getView method's parameter "position" is always 0, which makes the method pretty useless.

Here is the code of my customAdapter, extending BaseAdapter:

```
public class CreateProgramAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<TrainingPass> trainingPasses;
    private List<TrainingPass> items;
    private Context context;

    public CreateProgramAdapter(Context context, List<TrainingPass> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public TrainingPass getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        TrainingPassHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_createprogram_trainingpasses_item, parent, false);
            holder = new TrainingPassHolder();

            System.out.println(position);
            holder.trainingPass = this.getItem(position);
            holder.trainingPassContainer = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.trainingPassContainer);
            holder.trainingPassHeadlineShowHide = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trainingpass_headline);
            holder.noExercisesYet = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_no_exercises_yet);
            holder.exerciseSearchField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.trainingpass_exercise_searchfield);
            holder.trainingPassSetsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.trainingpass_sets_listview);
            holder.exercisesListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.exercises_listview);
            holder.addSetButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_set_button);
            holder.addExerciseButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_exercise_button);


            holder.trainingPassContainer.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
            holder.trainingPassHeadlineShowHide.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
            holder.noExercisesYet.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
            holder.exerciseSearchField.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
            holder.trainingPassSetsListView.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
            holder.exercisesListView.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
            holder.addSetButton.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
            holder.addExerciseButton.setTag(holder.trainingPass);

            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            view = convertView;
            holder = (TrainingPassHolder)view.getTag();
        }

        setupItems(holder);

        return view;
    }


    private void setupItems(TrainingPassHolder trainingPassHolder) {
        int id = trainingPassHolder.trainingPass.trainingPassID;
        TextView showHide = trainingPassHolder.trainingPassHeadlineShowHide;

        showHide.setText("Trainingpass " + id);
    }

    private class TrainingPassHolder {
        TrainingPass    trainingPass;
        RelativeLayout  trainingPassContainer;
        TextView        trainingPassHeadlineShowHide;
        TextView        noExercisesYet;
        EditText        exerciseSearchField;
        ListView        trainingPassSetsListView;
        ListView        exercisesListView;
        Button          addSetButton;
        Button          addExerciseButton;
    }
}
```

As you can see I am syso'ing out the position, which is always 0!

Here is the xml layput for the items in the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Trainingpass"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:height="35dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/trainingpass_showhide_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:height="30dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/trainingPassContainer"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:id="@+id/trainingPassContainer"
        android:background="@color/blue_bg_neutral"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name of exercise"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@color/blue_bg_inputField"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/sets_container"
            android:background="@color/blue_bg_inputField"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_sets_for_exercise"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sets for exercise"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/add_set_button"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/add_set_button" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/trainingpass_sets_listview"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_sets_for_exercise"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_sets_for_exercise" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add set"
                android:id="@+id/add_set_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_sets_listview"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add exercise"
                android:id="@+id/add_exercise_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/add_set_button"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sets_container"
            android:id="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:background="@color/blue_bg_inputField"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_exercises"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Exercises"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt_no_exercises_yet"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txt_no_exercises_yet" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_no_exercises_yet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No exercises yet"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_exercises"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/exercises_listview"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_no_exercises_yet"
                android:layout_above="@+id/txt_no_exercises_yet" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the code where I'm calling the CreateProgramAdapter:

```
ArrayList<TrainingPass> trainingPasses = new ArrayList<TrainingPass>();

        TrainingPass trainingPass = new TrainingPass();
        trainingPass.trainingPassName = "wefwef";
        trainingPass.trainingPassID = 1;

        TrainingPass trainingPass2 = new TrainingPass();
        trainingPass2.trainingPassName = "rwefhtr";
        trainingPass2.trainingPassID = 2;

        trainingPasses.add(trainingPass);
        trainingPasses.add(trainingPass2);

        ListView trainingPassesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_trainingpasses);
        CreateProgramAdapter createProgramAdapter = new CreateProgramAdapter(CreateProgramActivity.this, trainingPasses);
        trainingPassesListView.setAdapter(createProgramAdapter);
```

No matter how many items are inserted in the listview, the adapters position in the getView method is always 0. Obviously I want it to return 0 for the first item only, then 1 and 2 and so on,
I can't figure out why I doesn't do that.

If there are more information needed to solve the problem, please just ask.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I just discovered something really odd. I tried adding another item to the list like this:

```
    TrainingPass trainingPass3 = new TrainingPass();
    trainingPass3.trainingPassName = "ffffrwwewefefhtr";
    trainingPass3.trainingPassID = 3;
```

The result of this is exactly the same as before. There are only made 2 Syso's in the terminal, writing out 0 (the position variable). Also the listview only has 2 items in it, even though I've added 3 to the adapter.

This must mean that the getview is called twice for one item and then the rest of the items are not called.

But still, I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Charef is right. Your asking to return 0 when should ask it to return the position of ItemId.

Comment: help us understand your problem by adding more details

Comment: did you replace the  return 0; with return position; ?

Comment: Show the code where the call to CreateProgramAdapter() is made. Overriding getItemId is not required and you're not using it, you may remove it. And...it seems you have updated the code, pls update for us to help.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid I've added the where I'm calling the CreateProgramAdapter

Comment: @CharefEddineMechalikh I've added a bit more detail about what I want the code to do and how I call the CreateProgramAdapter. Don't know if you need more. But if you do, just ask.

Answer (score 10):

This error will happen if you put a ListView inside a ScrollView. ListView itself does vertical scroll so it must not be put into a ScrollView.

An adapter will call getView when listView need new item to show. So, if your listView not scroll, no new item be created, and no call to getView.

Comment: what is solution of this if we need to put listview inside scrollview...

Comment: It depends, for me this was a solution since I needed to have few items displayed on the child ListView http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353515/how-to-make-multiplelistview-in-scrollview/18354096#18354096 take a look and see if this will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

replace this

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

with this

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Edit2: comparing ith my baseadapter i suggest the following

replace this

```
holder.trainingPass = this.getItem(position);
```

by this

```
holder.trainingPass = items.getItem(position);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I completely overlooked that, but unfortunately the position variable is still 0 all the way.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the variable "position", which is one of the parameters in the getView method.
- public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent). The above Edit2 didn't solve the problem im afraid :(

Comment: I've found the solution and posted an answer myself. Anyways thanks a lot for your help. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

In your call to **CreateProgramAdapter**, I suspect you're not passing the correct context for your adapter.
Change from:

```
new CreateProgramAdapter(CreateProgramActivity.this, ...
```

TO:

```
new CreateProgramAdapter(getActivity(), ...
```

Note:

- CreateProgramActivity must be static in scope but I feel it is not the correct activity all the time, sometimes it is more dynamic. Method **getActivity** is more accurate, easy to do if the code is in a Fragment. However getting the correct activity may be difficult. Let's try it out and see...

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to call the getActivity method. Is it a part of a specific class? Android Studio can't find the method. If I force it to call getActivity() anyways it says "cannot resolve method getActivity()"

Comment: I've found the solution and posted an answer myself. Anyways thanks a lot for your help. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ListView widget's layout width and height to "match_parent".