# Use Scroll View In Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

How to use Scroll Properly in Android.I have to put some part of my layout into a scroll view .please help me to get this

My XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:onClick="goBack"
            android:src="@drawable/back_button" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Traveller Details"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
   <!-- from here i want to put it into a scroll view -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tittleLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TittleTravellerDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Traveller Details" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/passengerDetails"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tittleLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Tittle"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="First Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/LastName"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="Last Name" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/passengerList"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="166dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ContactDetailsLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passengerDetails"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TittleContactDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ContactDetails" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mobileEmailDetails"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ContactDetailsLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobileNumber"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Mobile No" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailid"
            android:layout_width="284dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Email ID" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/continueBooking"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mobileEmailDetails"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/continuebooking"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/searchflight" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Till here i want to put it into a scroll view -->
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you check the HorizontalScrollView and VerticalScrollView?. You just need to wrap the content that you want to make scrollable into one of these two ScrollView.

Comment: which part you want to put in scrollview?

Comment: Just put all you want in a ScrollView into a linear/relative layout, since ScrollView only accept one child.

Comment: @TarunDroid from passengerDetails layout till end

Answer (score 7):

You should pass a scrollView only one tag . . .

**Like This:**

```
<ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/scroll_id"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:scrollbars="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <!-- from here i want to put it into a scroll view -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tittleLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TittleTravellerDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Traveller Details" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/passengerDetails"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tittleLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Tittle"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="First Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/LastName"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="Last Name" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/passengerList"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="166dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ContactDetailsLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passengerDetails"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TittleContactDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ContactDetails" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mobileEmailDetails"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ContactDetailsLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobileNumber"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Mobile No" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailid"
            android:layout_width="284dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Email ID" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/continueBooking"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mobileEmailDetails"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/continuebooking"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/searchflight" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Till here i want to put it into a scroll view -->
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to add scroll view:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">



<com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.VideoPlayback.JustifiedTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/info_frame_text"

        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


     </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your whole code with scrollview in it:

As there can be only one layout inside the scrollview, you will need to take the whole layout inside one linear layout as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:onClick="goBack"
            android:src="@drawable/back_button" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Traveller Details"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

   <!-- from here i want to put it into a scroll view -->

   <ScrollView 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tittleLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TittleTravellerDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Traveller Details" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/passengerDetails"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tittleLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Tittle"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="First Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/LastName"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="Last Name" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/passengerList"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="166dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ContactDetailsLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passengerDetails"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TittleContactDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ContactDetails" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mobileEmailDetails"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ContactDetailsLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobileNumber"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Mobile No" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailid"
            android:layout_width="284dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Email ID" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/continueBooking"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mobileEmailDetails"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/continuebooking"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/searchflight" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <!-- Till here i want to put it into a scroll view -->
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if the ListView visibility is visible it is not working scroll is not coming properly

Comment: from tittleLayout till end i have to put in a scoll view so when i will set the proeprty of ListView to wrap_content complete page will ve visible in scroll

Answer (score 0):

Try this, also  make sure that  `android:layout_below` is given for `ScrollView` only Not for views inside `ScrollView`

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:onClick="goBack"
            android:src="@drawable/back_button" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Traveller Details"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- from here i want to put it into a scroll view -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tittleLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TittleTravellerDetails"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Traveller Details" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="2dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:background="#FF909090" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/passengerDetails"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/Tittle"
                    android:layout_width="290dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/firstName"
                    android:layout_width="290dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:hint="First Name"
                    android:maxLines="1" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/LastName"
                    android:layout_width="290dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:hint="Last Name"
                    android:maxLines="1" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/passengerList"
                    android:layout_width="290dp"
                    android:layout_height="166dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ContactDetailsLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TittleContactDetails"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="ContactDetails" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="2dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:background="#FF909090" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mobileEmailDetails"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ContactDetailsLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/mobileNumber"
                    android:layout_width="290dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:hint="Mobile No"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:maxLines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/emailid"
                    android:layout_width="284dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:hint="Email ID" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/continueBooking"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/mobileEmailDetails"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/continuebooking"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/searchflight" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Till here i want to put it into a scroll view -->
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..!

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:onClick="goBack"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Traveller Details"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
   <!-- from here i want to put it into a scroll view -->

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
            >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tittleLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TittleTravellerDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Traveller Details" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/passengerDetails"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tittleLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Tittle"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="First Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/LastName"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="Last Name" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/passengerList"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="166dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ContactDetailsLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passengerDetails"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TittleContactDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ContactDetails" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mobileEmailDetails"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ContactDetailsLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobileNumber"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Mobile No" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailid"
            android:layout_width="284dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Email ID" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/continueBooking"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mobileEmailDetails"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/continuebooking"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <!-- Till here i want to put it into a scroll view -->
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but when the listview is visible then the scroll view is not working

Comment: Yes bcoz...Using a ListView to make it not scroll is extremely expensive and goes against the whole purpose of ListView. You should NOT do this. Just use a LinearLayout instead.   Try this link you can get some idea about listview inside scrollview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android

Comment: so how could i do this