# Android gallery in ListView row

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I'm trying to achieve the effect such as Airbnb app for Android, list where in each rows is scrolled horizontally gallery (and each row have top layer with title an so). I'm using a `ListView` with `FrameLayout` and `ViewPager` in each cell, but I get a `NullPointerException` when scrolling. `Fragments` with pictures lose the pointer to the parent fragment (I found there is some bug in `Android Support Library`, I spent a few days searching for solution).

For now I do not want to show the code. I just would like to know is `Viewpager` in the `ListView` is a good idea, or maybe I have to do it in another way. Maybe there is a library for the implementation of such behavior?

Comment: if you don't show some source code and stacktrace nobody is going to be able to help you my friend

Comment: @alecnash, for now I just asking about same idea. I'd like to implement gallery on list (native Android Gallery widget is deprecated), like in Airbnb app and I want know that a ViewPager in ListView is a good choise or not. Maybe is a blind way and I should do it in other way.

Comment: if you google it you'll find a lot of stuff like this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429995/viewpager-and-listview-on-the-same-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on this page http://dorkus.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/01/16/021853. Needs some optimalizations, but imho it's a good base for future work.

### Edit

[View in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKhd9iU_YqU)

[image: List Item Layout]

[image: Item in List]

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

### row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### page1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### page2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00000000" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cc2828"
    android:text="削除"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### MyListAdapter.java

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private static final float BUTTON_WIDTH_DP = 70f;
    private int margin;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource,String[] items) {
        super(context, resource,items);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        //ページ2のRelativeLayoutの幅を計算してmarginへ格納する。
        float density = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; 
        int buttonWidthPX = (int) (BUTTON_WIDTH_DP * density + 0.5f);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getContext().getSystemService(getContext().WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display dp = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        margin = dp.getWidth() - buttonWidthPX;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
        }

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setPageMargin(-margin);
        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getContext(),getItem(position));
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

### MyPagerAdapter.java

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private static final int PAGE_NUM = 2;
    private String str;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Context context,String str) {
        super();
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.str = str;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        LinearLayout layout = null;
        if(position == 0){
            layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, null);
            TextView text = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText(str);
        }else{
            layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, null);
        }

        container.addView(layout);

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return PAGE_NUM;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {

        return view.equals(obj);
    }

}
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String str[] = {"項目1","項目2","項目3","項目4","項目5","項目6","項目7","項目8","項目9","項目10"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this,R.layout.row,str);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Samuel: still available in google cache http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3u0VjcD7Cp0J:yusuke-hata.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/01/16/021853+&cd=5&hl=pl&ct=clnk&gl=pl