# ListView Scrollable in Android

Tags: android, listview

I m getting problem in making ListView Scrollable. I know that listview is itself scrollable.But i have to put in ..Please tell how can i make listView Scrollable....Thankyou very much

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"



  android:layout_height="597dp"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewMob"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textViewCNIC"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewCNIC"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Customer Mobile No."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextViewMob"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextMob"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Customer Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextViewName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextViewName"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Mailing Address"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditTextAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextViewAdd"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextViewAdd"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewKin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextViewAdd"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/EditTextAdd"
    android:text="Customer&apos;s Next of Kin"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditTextKin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextViewKin"

       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextViewKin"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:ems="10"
       android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

 <EditText
  android:id="@+id/editTextName"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_above="@+id/EditTextAdd"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextViewName"
  android:ems="10" >


   </EditText>

  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewPhoto"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/TextViewKin"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/EditTextKin"
  android:text="Attach File"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <Button
  android:id="@+id/buttonCamera"
  style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewPhoto"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewPhoto"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
  android:text="From Camera" />

  <Button
  android:id="@+id/buttonAttach"
  style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonCamera"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonCamera"
  android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonCamera"
  android:text="From Sdcard" />



 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewCNIC"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonCamera"
  android:text="Customer CNIC"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <EditText
  android:id="@+id/EditTextCNIC"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewCNIC"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewCNIC"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewCNIC"
  android:ems="10"
  android:inputType="number" >


  </EditText>

  <EditText
  android:id="@+id/editTextMob"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditTextCNIC"
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/TextViewMob"
  android:ems="10"
  android:hint="Enter Ufone No. only"
  android:inputType="phone" />

  <Button
  android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditTextKin"
  android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
  android:text="Save and Open Account" />

  <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
  android:src="@drawable/cr_l0_button" />

  <ListView
  android:id="@+id/listView1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_above="@+id/EditTextKin"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">


  </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

i have also tried this: (may be there is problem in it )

```
         setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listviewattachment);//method call inonCreate  
    private  void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
     if (listAdapter == null) {
         // pre-condition
         return;
     }

     int totalHeight = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
         View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
         listItem.measure(0, 0);
         totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
     }

     ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
     params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() *     (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
     listView.setLayoutParams(params);

}
```

Comment: Similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` because `ListView` class implements its own scrolling behavior. So there will be issues in receiving gesture events because they all are handled by the parent `ScrollView`. Maybe you could rethink/redesign your layout a bit in order to avoid this solution.

Comment: but my form will not show all fields i mean it will not scroll...when i put ListView outside of scroll..it gives me error...:(

Comment: @user2768215 What error you are getting ?

Comment: Is the number of elements in your list static? I mean, do you get the data from some web service or not?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of views/fields is static, just remove the `ListView` and add the fields to the `ScrollView` child, which is not scrolling because you set a fixed height for the `RelativeLayout`; try setting just `wrap_content`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

Other tips.-

- `fill_parent` is deprecated, use `match_parent` instead.
- `RelativeLayout` has no `orientation` attribute, but actually you should replace the `RelativeLayout` for a `LinearLayout` vertical oriented, so you could remove all `below`/`above` atributes.