# ListView not showing all items

Tags: android-listview

I have a ListView and a button and i want to align button at the bottom of ListView, i had successfully align button at the bottom but the problem is that listview is showing only 1 row. But it has 6 rows. Please anybody help me.Thanks in advance

Here is My layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeNavBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_bar" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Edit Item"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:text="ItemName"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/EditItem_edtName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:text="Recurring"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/EditItem_toggleRecurring"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/EditItem_btnNotes"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:text="Notes"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:text="Priority"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/EditItem_radioGrp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/EditItem_radioLow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/EditItem_radioMedm"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/EditItem_radioHigh"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/EditItem_btnAddCategory"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:text="Add this item into category"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/EditItem_btnAssignment"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:text="Assignment"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/EditItem_lvStores"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:divider="@android:color/black"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                    android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
                    android:scrollingCache="false" >
                </ListView>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/EditItem_btnSave"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout
```

Comment: I suggest you to use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` because the `ListView` class implements its own scrolling and it just doesn't receive gestures because they all are handled by the parent `ScrollView`. Also you can find some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android)

Comment: What if the ListView is part of a collection of children of a ScrollView?