# Android listview not scrollable

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I have a profile page contains a linearlayout with some textviews and imageviews and a listview. (See picture)

[image]

The problem is that I want to make the whole page scrollable like in the twitter app instead of only the listview. So the listview need to extend to max height.

How can i force the listview to extend to max size and not be scrollable.

I linearlayout would be a second option but then it need to be possible to add a custom arrayadapter with a custom row like in the listview.

Comment: can you post your code also

Comment: As far as I understand you use vertical ListView. You can add your linearlayout to Header of you Listview and all page will be scrollable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make this in two ways:

#1 Adding `Header` to your `Listview`

```
  View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_header_layout, null);
  yourlistview.addHeader(header);
```

#2 You can set the list view height based on children.Call this fxn with your listview and keep all your widgets inside scrollview.

```
    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0, len = listAdapter.getCount(); i < len; i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0); 
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: I used the second function too force the listview to maxheight. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can put the scroll view as parent view and make your custom class for your list view.
You can check my answer by this link

[list view in scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android/17503823#17503823)

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollView to wrap your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   ......
</LinearLayout
</ScrollView>
```

Keep in mind that ScrollView takes in only one child.  So adjust your original layout accordingly.