# android scrollview wont scroll

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-scrollview

I've got some linearlayouts and some views in my scrollview which covers the whole screen. The problem is that I can see that one of my widgets is under the screen and it won't scroll down. This is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/topLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textDateTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/nullString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#FFCCFF99"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonReset"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="130sp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button"
                        android:text="@string/buttonResetText"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonFreeze"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="130sp"
                        android:layout_height="40sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button"
                        android:text="@string/buttonFreezeText"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loadBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="118dp"
                android:layout_height="118dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/sensorsGrid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#FFCCFF99"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="6"
                android:stretchMode="none" >
            </GridView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also add a GraphView to mainLayout in code like this

```
graph = new LineGraphView(this, "GraphViewDemo");
graph.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 300));
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
mainLayout.addView(graph);
```

Another problem is that if the GridView doesn't fit vertically to the mainlayout (cause it is larger) than the gridView becomes scrollable (which I don't want) and the GraphView which is below cannot be seen and I cant scroll down to it

UPDATE:
current xml

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
    android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FF023458"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/topLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textDateTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/nullString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#FFCCFF99"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonReset"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="130sp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button"
                        android:text="@string/buttonResetText"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonFreeze"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="130sp"
                        android:layout_height="40sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button"
                        android:text="@string/buttonFreezeText"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loadBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="118dp"
                android:layout_height="118dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/sensorsGrid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#FFCCFF99"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="6"
                android:stretchMode="none" >
            </GridView>
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: why don't you simply remove the parent RelativeLayout and instead make your ScrollView the parent?

Comment: oh yes good point, I removed it now, but still the same result :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add `GridView` inside `ScrollView`, because `GridView` itself is a scrollable view. A scrollable container inside another one will be taken over by the parent container (or vice versa) - causing not to scroll/appear properly on screen.

Tip: You should separate `ScrollView` and `GridView`. Or replace GridView with `TableLayout`.

Comment: thanks, Ill try it immediatally, but isnt there a way to remove "scrollability" from the gridView? because itll be better when the whole "screen" will be scrollable

Comment: removing scrolling ability from gridview will make it useless because its a recycling view. Instead, you should use TableLayout, which may act as gridview but without its own sroller.

Comment: @JuliusShadowAspectFlimmel : it's a hack here to override scrolling behavior http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android/14577399#14577399

Comment: I suppose Ill have to bring back the relativeLayout which was on the top and put scrollView and gridView inside it ?

Comment: Do you need to show quite many items in GridView? if not, then I guess sticking to TableLayout would be sufficient enough.

Comment: no I dont have to, I will read something about the TableLayout, then Ill decide which one to use, since I am a little bit low on time and it is now working with your solution and gridview, so many thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

change the scroll view tag to something like this, it will work for you.

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >
```

Comment: thanks, it helped, but you know, every device has different height so the scroll view wont cover whole screen on every device, will it?

Comment: @JuliusShadowAspectFlimmel : you shouldn't use fixed height for the ScrollView

Comment: No it won't so design your UI or XML as for the smallest screen your app is targetting. Then on larger devices the remaining part will remain blank. or use multiple scroll view. But remember, Each scroll view should have only one root element.

Comment: you know... but its a problem if Ill have a blank space... the gridView can have many rows and it will be annoying for the user to scroll it down when there is a blank space where the rows could have been

Comment: you can also make your scroll view as parent view, by removing the relative layout. it will then work on all size of screen devices.

Comment: yes, I have already removed the relative layout but no result :/ Ill update the code