# How to scroll ListView after the 6th row inside ScrollView on Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have referred NestedListView class answer in the below link it works fine,but I need to restrict the rows i.e if there are 6 rows no scroll greater than 6 rows scroll the listview with listrow clickable.
[ListView inside ScrollView is not scrolling on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android/17503823#17503823)

Comment: @muhammadaamirali how to solve this issue.

Comment: if you see the answer there it mentions you cannot have a `listView` in a `ScrollView` can you share the xml or have you used the same xml . If yes you might need to change it refer to the answer in the post

Comment: @MuhammadAamirAli is there any solution..