# How to use Listview inside Scrollview?

Tags: android, xml, listview, scroll, scrollview

I have a parent scrollview and a listview Inside it. The parent scrollview's property affects the child listview's scrolling property. I can't scroll the listview Only scrollview's other child views are scrolling. How can I solve this issue.

I used the following xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/newmenu_layout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/edit_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ImageList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
        </ListView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/videodetail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edt_stroke_bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/video_notes" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
                android:text="@string/videoattach" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/audiodetail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edt_stroke_bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgaudio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/audio_notes" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgaudio"
                android:text="Audio attachment" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawingdetail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edt_stroke_bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drawing_img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/video_notes" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drawing_img"
                android:text="Drawing attachment" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/edt_check"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edt_stroke_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="5dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/body"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Is there is any properties for listview or any listeners to fix the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `How to use Listview inside Scrollview?` **Please, don't**!! It's really a **WORST DESIGN** pattern.

Comment: You can scroll in Listview without using Scrollview

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView inside ScrollView is not scrolling on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

Your design is incorrect. You should never put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. `ListView` implements it own scrolling , and it won't receive any gesture as they are handled by the `ScrollView`. It won't work.

Comment: K. then give some idea. I have 3 different listview in an activtiy. Each list should show full list of contents. Thanks.