# Xamarin Forms List View Showing Row items in Frames

Tags: xaml, xamarin

Can you please recommend me some sample code to create framed lines as shown in the picture. As you can see in the image, for example for the first row, M should be in one frame and all the other 3 items in that row should be in another row.

Below please see my code, any help is appreciated.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XYZclass.Views.Exams.ExamsPage"
             Title="{Binding PageTitle}">

  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Image Source="XYZclassHeader.png" Aspect="AspectFit" />

    <Grid BackgroundColor="#0075c1">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text=""  TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
      <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Type:" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
      <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="Created:" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
      <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text="Finished:" TextColor="White"  HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </Grid>

    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Exams}" HorizontalOptions="Center">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
              <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Frame OutlineColor="Accent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalOptions="Center">
                  <Frame.Content>
                    <Label  Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />

                  </Frame.Content>
                </Frame>


                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Type}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding CreationDate}"  HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding CompletionDateInfo}"  HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

              </Grid>
            </ViewCell.View>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#0075c1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding DeleteSelectedExamsCommand}"/>
      </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
      <Label Text="Delete Selected(3) "
             TextColor="White" />
      <Label Text="&#xf014;"
            TextColor="White"
             FontSize="Large" />
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#0075c1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CreateNewExamCommand}"/>
      </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
      <Label Text="Create New Exam "
             TextColor="White"/>
      <Label Text="&#xf044;"
             TextColor="White"
            FontSize="Large"
            FontFamily="FontAwesome"/>
      <!--Note about FontAwesome for iOS: The FontFamily reference is for iOS. On android it will be ignored-->

    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: Page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ignore my previous answer, this is a much better answer to my own question: I have improved my code and now I create the items dynamically in the code behind, please use the following code if you need a similar screen:

Please see that I am creating "GridExams" dynamically in the code behind:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XYZProject.Views.Exams.ExamsPage"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XYZProject.Controls">

  <ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                iOS="10, 20, 10, 10"
                Android="0,0,0,0"/>
  </ContentPage.Padding>

  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Font" Value="Medium"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"/>
      </Style>
      <Style x:Key="LabelStyleSmall" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#41a4dc"/>
        <Setter Property="Font" Value="Small"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"/>
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <Grid RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
      <controls:Navigation/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid RowSpacing="0" Grid.Row="1" Padding="10,10,10,0">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="145*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="415*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="88*" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid Grid.Row="0" RowSpacing="10" BackgroundColor="#ed004a">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="#ed004a" Padding="30,0,0,0">
          <Label Text="Your personal exam history information"
                 Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                 HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1"
              BackgroundColor="#0075c1">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Label Grid.Column="0"
                 Text=""
                 Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
          <Label Grid.Column="1"
                 Text="Type:"
                 Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
          <Label Grid.Column="2"
                 Text="Created:"
                 Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
          <Label Grid.Column="3"
                 Text="Finished:"
                 Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
        </Grid>

      </Grid>

      <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollView>
          <Grid x:Name="GridExams">

          </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
      </Grid>

      <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Color="#0075c1" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="2"/>

      <Grid Grid.Row="3" Padding="0,0,0,10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="40*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Grid Grid.Column="0"
                BackgroundColor="{Binding DeleteButtonBackgroundColor}"
                Padding="30,0,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                   x:Name="LabelDeleteSelectedExamsPartOne"
                   Text="{Binding DeleteButtonText}"
                   Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>

            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   x:Name="LabelDeleteSelectedExamsPartTwo"
                   Text="&#xf014;"
                   Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                   Font="Large"/>

            <Grid.GestureRecognizers IsEnabled="{Binding DeleteButtonIsEnabled}">
              <TapGestureRecognizer
                  Command="{Binding DeleteSelectedExamsCommand}"/>
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
          </Grid>

          <Grid Grid.Column="2"
                BackgroundColor="#0075c1"
                Padding="30,0,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                   x:Name="LabelCreateNewExamPartOne"
                   Text="Create New Exam "
                   Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>

            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   x:Name="LabelCreateNewExamPartTwo"
                   Text="&#xf040;"
                   Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                   Font="Large"/>

            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer
                  Command="{Binding CreateNewExamCommand}"/>
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
          </Grid>

        </Grid>

      </Grid>

    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1"
      IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}"
      BackgroundColor="Black"
      Opacity="0.25">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <ActivityIndicator  Grid.Row="0"
                          IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}"
                          IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}"
                          VerticalOptions="End"
                          HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
      <Label Grid.Row="1"
             Text="Please wait..."
             TextColor="White"
             VerticalOptions="Start"
             HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

    </Grid>

  </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Method details that creates the grid dynamically:

```
private void CrateExamsGridDynamically()
    {
        GridExams.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection();
        GridExams.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        GridExams.Padding = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 5);

        Grid childContainer = new Grid();
        childContainer.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
        childContainer.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
        childContainer.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        childContainer.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection();
        childContainer.ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection()
        {
            new ColumnDefinition
            {
                Width =new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
            },
            new ColumnDefinition
            {
                Width=new GridLength(4, GridUnitType.Star)
            }
        };

        GridExams.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

        List<Exam> exams = App.ExamService.GetExams();

        int top = 0;

        foreach (var exam in exams)
        {
            childContainer.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition
            {
                Height = new GridLength(60, GridUnitType.Absolute)
            });

            exam.StartDateText = exam.StartDate.HasValue ? exam.StartDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yy") : string.Empty;
            exam.FinishedDateText = exam.FinishedDate.HasValue ? exam.FinishedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yy") : "In Progress >";
            string examType = string.Empty;
            switch (exam.Type)
            {
                case ExamTypes.Undefined:
                    break;
                case ExamTypes.Part1:
                    examType = "Part 1";
                    break;
                case ExamTypes.Part2:
                    examType = "Part 2";
                    break;
                case ExamTypes.Both:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            #region [ Left Grandchild Container ]

            Grid grandChildContainerLeft = new Grid();
            grandChildContainerLeft.BackgroundColor = Constants.CustomColour.RcpPurple;
            grandChildContainerLeft.Padding = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);

            #region [ Left Great Grandchild Container ]

            Grid greatGrandChildContainerLeft = new Grid();
            // TapGestureRecognizer for Left Container
            var grandChildContainerLeftTapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            grandChildContainerLeftTapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += GrandChildContainerLeftTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped;
            greatGrandChildContainerLeft.GestureRecognizers.Add(grandChildContainerLeftTapGestureRecognizer);
            greatGrandChildContainerLeft.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            greatGrandChildContainerLeft.Children.Add(new Label
            {
                Text = exam.Name,
                TextColor = Constants.CustomColour.RcpPurple,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
            }, 0, 0);
            // This is to carry exam id
            greatGrandChildContainerLeft.Children.Add(new Label
            {
                Text = exam.Id.ToString(),
                IsVisible = false
            }, 0, 0);

            #endregion

            grandChildContainerLeft.Children.Add(greatGrandChildContainerLeft, 0, 0);

            #endregion

            #region [ Right Grandchild Container ]

            Grid grandChildContainerRight = new Grid();
            grandChildContainerRight.BackgroundColor = Constants.CustomColour.RcpBlue;
            grandChildContainerRight.Padding = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);


            #region [ Right Great Grandchild Container ]

            Grid greatGrandChildContainerRight = new Grid();
            // TapGestureRecognizer for Right Container
            var grandChildContainerRightTapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            grandChildContainerRightTapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += GrandChildContainerRightTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped;
            greatGrandChildContainerRight.GestureRecognizers.Add(grandChildContainerRightTapGestureRecognizer);
            greatGrandChildContainerRight.BackgroundColor = Color.White;

            // We need three columns for each child grid
            greatGrandChildContainerRight.ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection()
            {
                new ColumnDefinition
                {
                    Width =new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
                },
                new ColumnDefinition
                {
                    Width=new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
                },
                new ColumnDefinition
                {
                    Width=new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star)
                }
            };

            // This is for type
            greatGrandChildContainerRight.Children.Add(new Label
            {
                Text = examType,
                TextColor = Constants.CustomColour.RcpBlue,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            }, 0, 0); // Exam type: the first column
            // This is to carry exam id
            greatGrandChildContainerRight.Children.Add(new Label
            {
                Text = exam.Id.ToString(),
                IsVisible = false
            }, 0, 0);

            // This is for created date
            greatGrandChildContainerRight.Children.Add(new Label
            {
                Text = exam.StartDateText,
                TextColor = Constants.CustomColour.RcpBlue,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            }, 1, 0); // Created: the second column

            // This is for finished date
            greatGrandChildContainerRight.Children.Add(new Label
            {
                Text = exam.FinishedDateText,
                TextColor = Constants.CustomColour.RcpBlue,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            }, 2, 0); // Finished: the third column 

            #endregion

            grandChildContainerRight.Children.Add(greatGrandChildContainerRight, 0, 0);

            #endregion

            childContainer.Children.Add(grandChildContainerLeft, 0, top); // First Column for grandChildContainerLeft
            childContainer.Children.Add(grandChildContainerRight, 1, top); // Second Column for grandChildContainerRight

            top++;
        }
        GridExams.Children.Add(childContainer, 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, grid column indices start at '0'(i.e., if u have 4 columns, their indices will be [0,1,2,3]).

Back to the question:

Your approach seems very strange: you put 4 elements in 4 grid cells 'independently', but 3 of this elements have to be placed within common border. You may try to put this 3 elements in another container(for example, in stack layout), and then add a border to this container. Frame class itself is very poor, [but here is some workaround](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57473/how-can-i-customize-the-border-of-stack-layout) using custom renderers.

Thus, listview cell may look like this:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <local:FrameWithBorder>
        <Label  Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
    </local:FrameWithBorder>
    <local:FrameWithBorder HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label  Text="{Binding Type}" />
            <Label  Text="{Binding CreationDate}" />
            <Label  Text="{Binding CompletionDateInfo}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </local:FrameWithBorder>
</StackLayout>
```

PS> I'm not much experienced in Xamarin, so, any suggestions and corrections would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** [do not put listview inside scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android/6211286#6211286)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers but this is I have implemented it, I mostly used Grid control, I am sharing it here in case you need a similar screen:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XYZclass.Views.Exams.ExamsPage"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XYZclass.Controls">

  <ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                iOS="10, 20, 10, 10"
                Android="0,0,0,10"/>
  </ContentPage.Padding>

  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Font" Value="Medium"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"/>
      </Style>
      <Style x:Key="LabelStyleSmall" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#41a4dc"/>
        <Setter Property="Font" Value="Small"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"/>
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <Grid RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
      <controls:Navigation/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid RowSpacing="0" Grid.Row="1" Padding="10,10,10,0">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="145*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="415*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="88*" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid Grid.Row="0" RowSpacing="10" BackgroundColor="#ed004a">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="#ed004a" Padding="30,0,0,0">
          <Label Text="Your personal exam history information"
                 Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                 HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1"
              BackgroundColor="#0075c1">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Label Grid.Column="0"
                 Text=""
                 Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
          <Label Grid.Column="1"
                 Text="Type:"
                 Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
          <Label Grid.Column="2"
                 Text="Created:"
                 Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
          <Label Grid.Column="3"
                 Text="Finished:"
                 Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
        </Grid>

      </Grid>

      <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView x:Name="ExamList"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Exams}"
                  HorizontalOptions="Center"
                  RowHeight="70">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                  <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Frame OutlineColor="#ed004a" Grid.Column="0">
                      <Frame.Content>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               Font="Large"
                               Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                               TextColor="#ed004a"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                      </Frame.Content>
                    </Frame>

                    <Frame OutlineColor="#ed004a" Grid.Column="1">
                      <Frame.Content>
                        <Grid>
                          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <Label Grid.Column="0"
                                 Text="{Binding Type}"
                                 Style="{StaticResource LabelStyleSmall}"/>
                          <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                 Text="{Binding StartDateText}"
                                 Style="{StaticResource LabelStyleSmall}"/>
                          <Label Grid.Column="2"
                                 Text="{Binding FinishedDateText}"
                                 Style="{StaticResource LabelStyleSmall}"/>
                        </Grid>
                      </Frame.Content>
                    </Frame>

                  </Grid>
                </ViewCell.View>
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
      </ScrollView>

      <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Color="#0075c1" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="2"/>

      <Grid Grid.Row="3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="40*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Grid Grid.Column="0"
                BackgroundColor="{Binding DeleteButtonBackgroundColor}"
                Padding="30,0,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                   x:Name="LabelDeleteSelectedExamsPartOne"
                   Text="{Binding DeleteButtonText}"
                   Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>

            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   x:Name="LabelDeleteSelectedExamsPartTwo"
                   Text="&#xf014;"
                   Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                   Font="Large"/>

            <Grid.GestureRecognizers IsEnabled="{Binding DeleteButtonIsEnabled}">
              <TapGestureRecognizer
                  Command="{Binding DeleteSelectedExamsCommand}"/>
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
          </Grid>

          <Grid Grid.Column="2"
                BackgroundColor="#0075c1"
                Padding="30,0,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                   x:Name="LabelCreateNewExamPartOne"
                   Text="Create New Exam "
                   Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>

            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   x:Name="LabelCreateNewExamPartTwo"
                   Text="&#xf040;"
                   Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                   Font="Large"/>

            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer
                  Command="{Binding CreateNewExamCommand}"/>
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
          </Grid>

        </Grid>

      </Grid>

    </Grid>

  </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```