# How can i put a border in a Grid on Xaml?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I like to put a Border in a Grid using Xaml. 
I found these code

```
`<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
<Grid>
   <!-- Grid contents here -->
</Grid>
</Border>`
```

But it doesn´t work. 
I'm a novice yet in this, I want to do a Table with some information.

Comment: The border control is from UWP, in Xamarin Forms you could use a Frame > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.frame?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: You can use Grid for this. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060644/xamarin-forms-list-view-showing-row-items-in-frames/35654474#35654474) for a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Border control in Xamarin.Forms, however you can use a `Frame`

```
<Frame OutlineColor="YourColor" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0">
  <Grid>
  </Grid>
</Frame>
```

Note the `OutlineColor`property, and the `Padding`, sometimes people forget that `Frame` as a default Padding that can overlap their childs.

Comment: I want to do a table, I have a grid where you specify meeting schedules but they look disorganized. But I don´t know how to separate the rows. Thanks for the help

Comment: You can have the same effect using BoxViews. Do you have a sketch of what you want to accomplish?