# Scrollview of Expandablelistview

Tags: android, scrollview, expandablelistview

I have bunch of buttons,expandablelistviews and textviews in my xml.When my items started to fill whole screen,I used scrollview.It works fine but it does not let my expandablelistview's scrollview to work.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#A4A4A4"
android:weightSum="1">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_button"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
            android:src="@drawable/home_ico"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/internet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
            android:text="@string/internet"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/servisler"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
            android:text="@string/servisler"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/kampanya"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
            android:text="@string/kampanya"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cihazlar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
            android:text="@string/hakkımızda"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Diğer" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.4">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.8">
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_sonet_teknoloji_title"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/servisler_guvenlik_detay"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_sonet_teknoloji_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:text="Detaylı bilgi..."/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/lvExp5"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title1"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content1"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title2"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content2"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title3"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content3"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title4"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content4"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title5"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content5"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title6"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content6"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title7"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content7"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title8"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content8"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title9"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content9"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title10"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content10"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title11"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content11"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title12"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content12"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title13"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content13"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title14"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content14"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title15"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content15"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_title16"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:text="@string/servisler_guvenlik_content16"/>


        </LinearLayout>
```

So any suggestion?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android/6211286#6211286

Comment: Nesting scrollable containers is never a good idea.

Comment: @Ali Yılmaz, why you are adding scrollview in child view ?

Comment: scroll view can not apply directly on expandable list view, Grid view, recycle view etc.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answers.I implement OnTouchListener for expandablelistview and it is scrollable right now.And the solution is here as @AmitVaghela said:[ListView inside ScrollView is not scrolling on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android/6211286#6211286)