# Wheel Picker not working inside scrollbar Android

Tags: android, uipickerview, android-wheel

In my application I am trying to use a **WheelPicker**  by [Bruicetoo](https://github.com/brucetoo/PickView) its working fine but as I out it inside `ScrollView` it stops responding and only activity is scrolled but I am unable to scroll the WheelPicker. I have also tried `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` in picker but didn't work. Minimum SDK version is 21 and target v. 23.

**Updated Code**

**Layout:**

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <com.bruce.pickerview.LoopView
            android:id="@+id/loop_view"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/calendar_view"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            app:canLoop="true"
            app:centerTextColor="#ff000000"
            app:drawItemCount="7"
            app:initPosition="3"
            app:lineColor="@color/PrimaryBlue"
            app:textSize="12sp"
            app:topBottomTextColor="#ffafafaf" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Code:**

```
loopView = (LoopView) findViewById(R.id.loop_view);
        loopView.setInitPosition(2);
        loopView.setCanLoop(false);
        loopView.setLoopListener(new LoopScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelect(int i) {
                     Toast.makeText(RegisterRoomActivity.this, StartHr.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        loopView.setTextSize(25);//must be called before setDateList
        loopView.setDataList(StartHr);
```

Comment: Its because scrollable view inside ScrollView creates problem. You can write the code such that when your loopview is scrolling, scrollview does not scroll and when scrollview is scrolling, your loopview should be stable. Try to use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android

Comment: Try setting `FillViewPort` to `true` on the `ScrollView`.

Comment: @Ironman unfortunately didnt worked for me

Comment: Does your issue solved?