# How to use scrollView in Tabbed Activity - Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-viewpager, scrollview

Does anyone know how you can use `ScrollView` in a `fragment` using the `Tabbed Activity Template` when creating a new `activity`. It uses a `viewPager` by default, and I've made 3 tabs with 3 different layouts which I can slide through. But every time i try to use the `ScrollView` in any one of these tabs the program gets buggy and nothing happens, sometimes i can't even swipe. So, in different words:

My Question: What is the proper way to use `scrollview` in a `tab(fragment)` when using the default `tabbed activity template` with `ViewPager`?

**UPDATE 1**

The thing with `NestedScrollView` worked, but now this is the new problem that came along with the solution. The AppBar scrolls along with the other stuff. How can i fix this?

[CLICK HERE TO SEE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKPuq.jpg)

**UPDATE 2**

It looks like the `scrollView` has an effect on this type of `AppBar` (Toolbar to be more specific), and i just fixed the problem by adding `app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlwaysCollapsed"` to `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>`, and it's now stationary.

**Additional link:**

*https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html#SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS_COLLAPSED*

Comment: Try the answer below - I believe I had an issue like this before!

Comment: This use case is widely covered in tutorials and you can find answers to the issues presented while implementing it here on SO. The advice from @Eenvincible sounds right to me. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons that might seem unclear to most of us, it is hard for touch events to be differentiated when you want to scroll vs swipe.

To solve this, I used a NestedScrollView instead of the regular ScrollView.

The other option would be to catch the events and override them - obviously more complicated to do but possible.

You can take a look at my recent code on [github](https://github.com/echirchir/aVerse/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_poems_tab.xml) for an example.

Good luck and please let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer! It worked, but partially. Now the whole action bar with the tabs is moving when I scroll up and down. Any idea why is that, and how to fix it? I'm gonna see what i can do, and if I find a fix, I'll give you the updates.

Just to add, i havent done anything different to the default template by android, that's why I'm not uploading any code.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android

Comment: Thanks, I checked it, but couldn't find out why my appbar is moving when I scroll. Any other Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       your content here.........

   </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```