# Android: Listview inside Listview, not scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a ListView of date and related events.
The events form another listView.

The parent list should be scrollable, but its not scrolling.
Any issue with multi-level listview scrolling?

Comment: Use recyclerview instead, as nested listview scrolls are hard to handle

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android

Comment: you shouldn't use one scroll container inside another. It is a bad idea from the start. Maybe ExpandableListVIew is what you need?