# Can't scroll ListView inside ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

While trying to create news feed in my app, I've created custom ListView Adapter. My single ListView item has an ImageView, WebView and ListView. So I have a ListView inside a ListView. The problem is, when I try to scroll the inner ListView, the outer ListView is being scrolled. What should I change to avoid the problem?

My custom adapter:

```
public class TestCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<String> imageNames = null;
    private List<String> descriptions = null;
    private List<String> innerLVitems = null;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;

    public FirstFragmentLVAdapter(Context context, List<String> imageNames, List<String> descriptions, List<String> innerLVitems) {
        this.imageNames = imageNames;
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
        this.innerLVitems = innerLVitems;
        this.context = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return innerLVitems.size();
    }


    public Object getItem(int position) {
        List <String> returnedList = new ArrayList<>();
        returnedList.add(imageNames.get(position));
        returnedList.add(descriptions.get(position));
        returnedList.add(innerLVitems.get(position));
        return returnedList;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.firstfragment_listview_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventImage);
            holder.description = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventDescriptionWV);
            holder.LV = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.LV);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



            holder.image.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageNames.get(position), "drawable", context.getPackageName()));

            String webViewText = "<html><body><p align=\"justify\">"+
                    descriptions.get(position)+"</p></body></html>";
            holder.description.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, webViewText, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

            String [] items = innerLVitems.get(position).split("\\s*,\\s*");
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items);
            holder.LV.setAdapter(adapter);


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        WebView description;
        ListView LV;
    }

}
```

My listview item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/eventImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/autumn" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/eventDescriptionWV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/eventImage"></WebView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/eventDescriptionWV"
    android:text="Text" />

<ListView
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/LV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/label" />
```

Comment: you cant scroll two scroll at once in one direction .

Comment: where is the scrollview in your layout? put your code here

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra There is no ScrollView. I use ListView.

Comment: I think this would help <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for my case. I needed to add this line to the inner ListView XML:

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

This only works only for Lollipop and up though.

Answer (score 1):

To use 2 nested `ListViews`  you sh to use an `ExpandableListView` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html.

Using 2 `ListViews` the Android will always apply the scroll on the first one it finds. The `ExpandableListView` component is specific for working with sublists within lists.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `RecyclerView`with `NestedScrollView` and turn off `RecyclerView`'s nested scrolling. This way you can have multiple scrollable items along same orientation.