# How to create ScrollView in my layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want my ScrollView to join my StackLayout and my list so I can scroll it down, an example I saw that worked out was the one below but I was not able to implement it at my command

The way it is now it's from a scrowview in the List

[This example worked out](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/)

[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         NavigationPage.TitleIcon="logoD">
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout x:Name="topo">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Scale="1.0" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="250">
                <Image.Source>
                    <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding img}" CacheValidity="5" CachingEnabled="True"/>
                </Image.Source>
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>

    <ListView x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell >
                    <Grid Padding="5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Spacing="4"  VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Categoria}" TextColor="#38B6AB"  FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Data}" TextColor="#666666" FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding hora}" TextColor="#474747" Font="Bold" FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: My StackLayout top does not enter the scrowview

Comment: Somente listview suporta rolagem, StackLayout stays fixed

Comment: You can't have an ListView inside a ScrollView, the scroll event handled in one of they hides the another handler as you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android/6211286#6211286

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListView inside ScrollView is not scrolling on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put a ListView inside a ScrollView as they both implement scrolling. What you should do is use the [Header](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.Header/) template of the ListView to put your Grid there. That way it will scroll with the ListView.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    NavigationPage.TitleIcon="logoD">
    <ListView x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
      <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Scale="1.0" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="250">
              <Image.Source>
                <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding img}" CacheValidity="5" CachingEnabled="True"/>
              </Image.Source>
              <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped" />
              </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate
      </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <Grid Padding="5">
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Spacing="4"  VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="{Binding Categoria}" TextColor="#38B6AB"  FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Data}" TextColor="#666666" FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding hora}" TextColor="#474747" Font="Bold" FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
              </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </ContentPage>
```

Comment: So the listview overlays the stacklayout, page is only with the listview

Comment: @José The StackLayout you had there was irrelevant and I removed it. Try again with the current code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement with this same example command

```
<ContentPage.Content>
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MonkeysGrouped}"
            ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
            ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            GroupShortNameBinding = "{Binding Key}"
            IsGroupingEnabled = "true"
            GroupDisplayBinding = "{Binding Key}">
     <ListView.Header>
      <cv:CarouselView x:Name="CarouselZoos" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BindingContext.Zoos, Source={x:Reference MonkeysPage}}" HeightRequest="200">
        <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
              <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#80000000" Padding="12">
                  <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
              </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
        </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
      </cv:CarouselView>
    </ListView.Header>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <controls:CircleImage
                   BorderColor="Aqua"
                   BorderThickness="3"
                   HeightRequest="66"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   Aspect="AspectFill"
                   WidthRequest="66"
                   Grid.RowSpan="2"
                   Source="{Binding Image}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                   VerticalOptions="End"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   VerticalOptions="Start"
                   Text="{Binding Location}"/>
          </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```