# ListView within ScrollView show all elements and don't scroll

Tags: android, listview

I have an android app, that looks like this:

[image]

The whole view is contained within a `ScrollView` because if the app is rotated in landscape mode, the content does not fit the screen.

Now the part with the red marked area is a `ListView`, that contains the result from the previous matches. Now the issue is, that the `ListView` itself only shows one entry and for the rest, the user has to scroll the `ListView`.

But I want the `ListView` to always show all entries without any scrolling and only scroll the parent.

Is there any way to archive that, without creating a [NestedListView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17503823/2977288) class or something like that?

Comment: One of the first things I learnt about ListView and ScrollView is that you don't have to put the first one inside the second one... probably it's better if you keep it out

Comment: You could try replacing the scrollview with a recyclerview. Just do multiple viewholders. One for the content above the red box, one for each set of previous matches, and whatever else below it.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by adding android:fillViewport="true" to your ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  android:scrollbars="vertical">

<ListView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:divider="@null"/>
```

or, In java

```
mScrollView.setFillViewport(true);
```