# SwipeCardView doesnt work well on a scroll View

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin.Forms and I am trying to do a kind of Tinder interaction. At the moment all is working fine until I wrap that component into a ScrollView.
What is happening is that when I do the swipe it get stuck and I have to click on an element to put it on the right place (the app doesn't crash). I shared my code and I would be so glad if someone could help me.

```html
ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:swipeCardView="clr-namespace:MLToolkit.Forms.SwipeCardView;assembly=MLToolkit.Forms.SwipeCardView"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
             xmlns:gradient ="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.Graphics;assembly=Syncfusion.Core.XForms"
             x:Class="Ventazer.Views.AttendeeList">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryFormBackground}">
                <Label Text="No data Found" Margin="0,300,0,0" IsVisible="false" x:Name="lbl" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                <swipeCardView:SwipeCardView x:Name="swipeCardView" 
                                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}"
                                         SwipedCommand="{Binding SwipedCommand}"
                                         SupportedSwipeDirections="Left, Right"
                                         SupportedDraggingDirections="Left,Right"
                                         DraggingCommand="{Binding DraggingCommand}"
                                         Threshold="{Binding Threshold}"
                                         Padding="0"
                                         Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <swipeCardView:SwipeCardView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                                     RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"
                                     x:Name="Prueba">
                                <Frame Padding="0"
                                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">
                                    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="absoluteContent" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                                                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">
                                        <!-- Image Profile -->
                                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding UserImage}"
                                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,0.5,1,1"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                                           RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                                           RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"/>
                                        <!-- Black gradient overlay Background-->
                                        <gradient:SfGradientView >
                                            <gradient:SfGradientView.BackgroundBrush>
                                                <gradient:SfLinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5, 0.5" EndPoint="0.5, 1">
                                                    <gradient:SfLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                        <gradient:SfGradientStop Color="{StaticResource Transparent}" Offset="0.0"/>
                                                        <gradient:SfGradientStop Color="{StaticResource Black}" Offset="1.0" />
                                                    </gradient:SfLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                </gradient:SfLinearGradientBrush>
                                            </gradient:SfGradientView.BackgroundBrush>
                                        </gradient:SfGradientView>
                                        <!-- Info of the person -->
                                        <!-- name -->
                                        <Label x:Name="profileName"
                                           Text="{Binding UserNameAge}"
                                           TextColor="{StaticResource White}"
                                           FontSize="24"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 30"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional, WidthProportional"/>
                                        <!-- Ocupation -->
                                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="Occupation_icon.png"
                                                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.07,0.6, 35, 35"
                                                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding UserOccupation}"
                                           TextColor="{StaticResource White}"
                                           FontSize="20"
                                           FontAttributes="None"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.7, 0.6, 300, 30"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>
                                        <!-- Location -->
                                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="Location_icon.png"
                                                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.07,0.7, 35, 35"
                                                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding UserLocation}"
                                           TextColor="{StaticResource White}"
                                           FontSize="20"
                                           FontAttributes="None"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.7, 0.7, 300, 30"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>
                                        <!-- Like squere feedback-->
                                        <Frame x:Name="LikeFrame"
                                           BorderColor="{StaticResource AquaGreen}"
                                           BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                           Padding="0"
                                           CornerRadius="20"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.1,.1, 150, 50"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                           Rotation="-10"
                                           Opacity="0">
                                            <Label x:Name="LikeText"
                                               Text="LET'S GO"
                                               TextColor="{StaticResource AquaGreen}"
                                               BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                               FontSize="20"></Label>
                                        </Frame>
                                        <!-- Nope squere feedback-->
                                        <Frame x:Name="NopeFrame"
                                           BorderColor="{StaticResource PinkCarmesi}"
                                           BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                           Padding="0"
                                           CornerRadius="20"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.9,.1, 150, 50"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                           Rotation="10"
                                           Opacity="0">
                                            <Label Text="NOPE"
                                               TextColor="{StaticResource PinkCarmesi}"
                                               BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                               FontSize="20"></Label>
                                        </Frame>
                                        <!-- Button Nope -->
                                        <Button x:Name="nopeButton"
                                            WidthRequest="60"
                                            HeightRequest="60"
                                            BorderRadius="30"
                                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.1, 0.85, 60, 60"
                                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                            Clicked="OnNopeClicked"
                                            />
                                        <Button WidthRequest="60"
                                            HeightRequest="60"
                                            BorderRadius="30"
                                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Carmesi}"
                                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.1, 0.85, 60, 60"
                                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                            InputTransparent="true"
                                            />
                                        <Image Source="thumbs_down.png"
                                           WidthRequest="60"
                                           HeightRequest="60"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.1, 0.855, 60, 60"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                           InputTransparent="True"/>
                                        <!--Button check profile-->
                                        <Button x:Name="profileButton"
                                            WidthRequest="60"
                                            HeightRequest="60"
                                            BorderRadius="30"
                                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.85, 60, 60"
                                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                            Clicked="OnProfileClicked"/>
                                        <Button WidthRequest="60"
                                            HeightRequest="60"
                                            BorderRadius="30"
                                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.85, 60, 60"
                                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                            InputTransparent="true"/>
                                        <Image Source="profile_icon.png"
                                           WidthRequest="60"
                                           HeightRequest="60"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.85, 60, 60"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                           InputTransparent="true"/>
                                        <!-- Button Let's go -->
                                        <Button x:Name="likeButton"
                                            WidthRequest="60"
                                            HeightRequest="60"
                                            BorderRadius="30"
                                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.9, 0.85, 60, 60"
                                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                            Clicked="OnLikeClicked"/>
                                        <Button WidthRequest="60"
                                            HeightRequest="60"
                                            BorderRadius="30"
                                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AquaGreen}"
                                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.9, 0.85, 60, 60"
                                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                            InputTransparent="true"/>
                                        <Image Source="thumbs_up.png"
                                           WidthRequest="60"
                                           HeightRequest="60"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.9, 0.85, 60, 60"
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                           InputTransparent="true"/>
                                    </AbsoluteLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <!--<Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            
                            <Frame CornerRadius="0"
                                   Padding="0"
                                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="imgUserImage"
                                                            LoadingPlaceholder="default_placeholder.png"
                                                            Source="{Binding UserImage}"
                                                            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                                                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                                                            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                                                            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"/>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>-->
                            <!--<Frame CornerRadius="5" Padding="0" Margin="30,30,30,0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource white}">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource white}">
                                -->
                            <!-- UserImage-->
                            <!--
                                <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="imgUserImage" LoadingPlaceholder="default_placeholder.png" Aspect="Fill" Source="{Binding UserImage}" HeightRequest="300" DownsampleToViewSize="true" />
                                <Label x:Name="userName" Text="{Binding UserName}" TextColor="{StaticResource darkTextColor}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource white}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize}" Margin="10">
                                </Label>
                                <Label x:Name="eventName" Text="{Binding EventName}" HeightRequest="50" TextColor="{StaticResource white}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="{StaticResource LargeFontSize}" Margin="0,10,0,10" FontFamily="{StaticResource LightFont}"
                                    VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                </Label>
                                <Button BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryButton}" Text="View Profile" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" TextColor="{StaticResource white}" BorderRadius="0" FontFamily="{StaticResource NormalFont}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize}" CornerRadius="5" Margin="10,0,10,10" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>-->
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </swipeCardView:SwipeCardView.ItemTemplate>
                </swipeCardView:SwipeCardView>
                <StackLayout x:Name="profileDetail"
                        IsVisible="false">
                    <StackLayout Margin="28, 20, 26, 34">
                        <Label Text="Mobile/Phone"
                           FontSize="16"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           TextColor="{StaticResource Dark}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding UserPhone}"
                           FontSize="16"
                           FontAttributes="None"
                           TextColor="{StaticResource Dark}"
                           Margin="0, 0, 0, 20"/>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                 Margin="0, 0, 0, 20">
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="Interests_icon"
                                                    Margin="0, 0, 4, 0"/>
                            <Label Text="Interests"
                           FontSize="16"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           TextColor="{StaticResource Dark}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                            <Label Text="{Binding UserInterest}"
                               FontSize="16"
                               FontAttributes="None"
                               TextColor="{StaticResource Dark}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>

                <!--<Label x:Name="attendeecount" IsVisible="false" TextColor="{StaticResource Grey}" FontFamily="{StaticResource NormalFont}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="20,0,20,50" />-->
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

i also share a function that makes that my swipecard get smaller and show the details, ando some interfaces.

```html
        public void OnProfileClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Clic profile");
            if (expandProfile)
            {
                swipeCardView.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(0, 0, swipeCardView.Bounds.Width, swipeCardView.Bounds.Height - 200), 300, Easing.Linear);
                profileDetail.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(0, swipeCardView.Bounds.Height - 200, profileDetail.Bounds.Width, profileDetail.Bounds.Height + swipeCardView.Bounds.Height), 300, Easing.Linear);
                profileDetail.IsVisible = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                swipeCardView.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(0, 0, swipeCardView.Bounds.Width, swipeCardView.Bounds.Height + 200), 300, Easing.Linear);
                profileDetail.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(0, profileDetail.Bounds.Height, profileDetail.Bounds.Width, profileDetail.Bounds.Height - profileDetail.Bounds.Height), 300, Easing.Linear);
                profileDetail.IsVisible = false;
            }
            expandProfile = !expandProfile;
        }
```

[Stuck app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPEW3.png)

I will be so glad if someone can help me!

Comment: Please do not use ScrollView to cover `SwipeCardView`(actually `SwipeCardView` is a `ListView` in android). If do that, ListView inside ScrollView is not scrolling, you can refer to this thread.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/6211286/10627299

Comment: Thanks Leon, i have to not use a listView inside, insted of that i only use scroll view out side